# Check if multiple strings exist in another string

Tags: python, list, contains

How can I check if any of the strings in an array exists in another string?

For example:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
s = "a123"
if a in s:
    print("some of the strings found in s")
else:
    print("no strings found in s")
```

How can I replace the `if a in s:` line to get the appropriate result?

Comment: I'm surprised there aren't (yet) any answers comparing to a compiled regex in terms of perf, especially compared to size of the string and number of "needles" to search for.

Comment: @Pat I am not surprised. The question is not about performance. Today most programmers care more for getting it done and readability. The performance question is valid, but a different question.

Comment: regex `[abc]` also works perfectly well and will be faster if there are more than a couple of candidates to test. But if the strings are arbitrary and you don't know them in advance to construct a regex, you will have to use the `any(x in str for x in a)` approach.

Comment: This problem is a special case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342601/. The standard approach is to use `any`, as seen in the top answers; however, some string-specific optimizations may be possible.

Comment: Well I did look up this question for performance. Otherwise that’s a bachelor-grade algorithmic problem.

Answer (score 1262, accepted):

You can use [**`any`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
a_string = "A string is more than its parts!"
matches = ["more", "wholesome", "milk"]

if any(x in a_string for x in matches):
```

Similarly to check if *all* the strings from the list are found, use [**`all`**](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all) instead of `any`.

Comment: any() takes an iterable. I am not sure which version of Python you are using but in 2.6 you will need to put [] around your argument to any().

any([x in str for x in a])

so that the comprehension returns an iterable. But maybe later versions of Python already do this.

Comment: @Mark Byers: Sorry for the late comment, but is there a way to print the string that was found? How would you do this. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand, if a is the list, and str is the thing to match against, what is the x? Python newbie ftw. :)

Comment: @red: you can read `for x in a` like "for each element in list".  Since `a` is a list of strings, and `x` is an element of that list, `x` is a string (one of 'a', 'b', 'c' in original example)

Comment: @emispowder It works fine for me as-is in Python 2.6.9.

Comment: @emispowder: [Generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) were introduced in 2.4.

Comment: What is x representing in this ans

Comment: One caveat of using 'any' is that it verifies if each string of 'a' is in 'str'. You might want to return True as soon as one string of 'a' is in 'str'.
This would be faster.

Comment: @CodeGuru `x` is just a temporary variable when iterating through `a`. You could use a different name like `[number*2 for number in [7, 13]]`, but `[x*2 for x in [7, 13]]` seems to be a kind of convention.

Comment: Basically [x in str for x in a] returns a list of True/False depending on whether the string is found. The any() function iterates true that list of True/False and returns True if there is one True in the list.  @CodeGuru

Comment: I cleaned up the code to use `a_string` instead of Python reserved word `str` and `matches` instead of `a` because the reserved word was needlessly confusing (I know the poster had it, but still) and nested list comprehensions are impenetrable with single letter variables.

Comment: I can't figure out a way to match a capitalized word.
a_string = "A string is MORE than its parts!"
matches = ["MORE", "wholesome", "milk"]
This does not match 'MORE'. What's the issue here?

Comment: For a Python newbie, would any senior please expand `if any(x in a_string for x in matches):` to explicit loop? This seems not correct: `for x in a_string:
    print(x)
    if x in matches:
        print(f'{x=} is in the matches')`

Comment: @MathArt: generator expressions and list comprehensions are a little backwards from what you expect. The expression at the beginning (`x in a_string`) would be the final line if you expanded to a `for` loop. So `for x in matches: print(x in a_string)` will print a bunch of either True or False. If any one of those is True, the `any()` function will return True as well.

Comment: I think this is suboptimal because `x in a_string for x in matches` will evaluate all strings, output a list of booleans, then `any()` will loop over the list and break when `True` is found. Using a plain `for` loop allows you to break the loop as soon as the first element is found, avoiding unnecessary evaluations of the other strings.

Comment: @SteveJalim Replacing the generator expression with a list comprehension was just bad and not "modern" at all. Rolling back...

Comment: @AurélienPierre No, that doesn't create a list but a lazy iterator, and the whole thing also stops at the first find, just like your loop.

Answer (score 118):

`any()` is by far the best approach if all you want is `True` or `False`, but if you want to know specifically which string/strings match, you can use a couple things.

If you want the first match (with `False` as a default):

```
match = next((x for x in a if x in a_string), False)
```

If you want to get all matches (including duplicates):

```
matches = [x for x in a if x in a_string]
```

If you want to get all non-duplicate matches (disregarding order):

```
matches = {x for x in a if x in a_string}
```

If you want to get all non-duplicate matches in the right order:

```
matches = []
for x in a:
    if x in a_string and x not in matches:
        matches.append(x)
```

Comment: please add example for the last match too

Comment: @OlegKokorin: It creates a list of matching strings in the same order it finds them, but it keeps only the first one if two are the same.

Comment: Using an `OrderedDict` is probably more performant than a list. See [this answer on "Removing duplicates in lists"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390/4518341)

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: One nice thing about the first option (using next) is it allows for short-circuit evaluation, so if you just want to know, for example, when a failure happened, if it was any of a certain class of failures, you don't have to generate truth values for each comparison, just all of them until the first match is found.

Answer (score 67):

You should be careful if the strings in `a` or `str` gets longer. The straightforward solutions take O(S*(A^2)), where `S` is the length of `str` and A is the sum of the lenghts of all strings in `a`. For a faster solution, look at [Aho-Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm for string matching, which runs in linear time O(S+A).

Comment: can Aho-Corasick also find substrings instead of prefixes ?

Comment: Some python Aho-Corasick libraries are [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/) and [here](https://github.com/JanFan/py-aho-corasick)

Comment: is there a library for that?

Answer (score 43):

Just to add some diversity with **`regex`**:

```
import re

if any(re.findall(r'a|b|c', str, re.IGNORECASE)):
    print 'possible matches thanks to regex'
else:
    print 'no matches'
```

or if your list is too long - `any(re.findall(r'|'.join(a), str, re.IGNORECASE))`

Comment: This works for the given use case of the question. If the you search for `(` or `*` this fails, since quoting for the regex syntax needs to be done.

Comment: You can escape it if necessary with `'|'.join(map(re.escape, strings_to_match))`. You sould probably `re.compile('|'.join(...))` as well.

Comment: And What's the time complexity ?

Answer (score 19):

A surprisingly fast approach is to use `set`:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a_string = "a123"
if set(a) & set(a_string):
    print("some of the strings found in a_string")
else:
    print("no strings found in a_string")
```

This works if `a` does not contain any multiple-character values (in which case use `any` as listed [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389611/122033)). If so, it's simpler to specify `a` as a string: `a = 'abc'`.

Answer (score 14):

You need to iterate on the elements of a.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
a_string = "a123"
found_a_string = False
for item in a:    
    if item in a_string:
        found_a_string = True

if found_a_string:
    print "found a match"
else:
    print "no match found"
```

Comment: Yes i knew how to do that but compared to Marks answer, that's horrible code.

Comment: Only if you understand Mark's code.  The problem you were having is that you weren't examining the elements of your array.  There are a lot of terse, pythonic ways to accomplish what you want that would hide the essence of what was wrong with your code.

Comment: It may be 'horrible code' but it's [exactly what any() does](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any). Also, this gives you the actual string that matched, whereas any() just tells you there is a match.

Answer (score 4):

jbernadas already mentioned the [Aho-Corasick-Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) in order to reduce complexity.

Here is one way to use it in Python:

1. Download aho_corasick.py from [here](https://gist.github.com/atdt/875e0dba6a15e3fa6018)
2. Put it in the same directory as your main Python file and name it `aho_corasick.py`
3. Try the alrorithm with the following code:

   ```
   from aho_corasick import aho_corasick #(string, keywords)

   print(aho_corasick(string, ["keyword1", "keyword2"]))
   ```

Note that the search is *case-sensitive*

Comment: This would be better as a comment on, or edit to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

The [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module recommended in python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), supports this

```
words = {'he', 'or', 'low'}
p = regex.compile(r"\L<name>", name=words)
m = p.findall('helloworld')
print(m)
```

output:

```
['he', 'low', 'or']
```

Some details on implementation: [link](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/issues/11)

Comment: I can't find any documentation on \L. Can you point me to it?

Comment: @DaniloSouzaMorães https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#named-lists-hg-issue-11

Answer (score 3):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str =  "a123"

a_match = [True for match in a if match in str]

if True in a_match:
  print "some of the strings found in str"
else:
  print "no strings found in str"
```

Answer (score 3):

A compact way to find multiple strings in another list of strings is to use set.intersection. This executes much faster than list comprehension in large sets or lists.

```
>>> astring = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']
>>> bstring = ['def', 'jkl']
>>> a_set = set(astring)  # convert list to set
>>> b_set = set(bstring)
>>> matches = a_set.intersection(b_set)
>>> matches
{'def', 'jkl'}
>>> list(matches) # if you want a list instead of a set
['def', 'jkl']
>>>
```

Comment: The input is specified as a list of strings vs. a longer string that might contain them as a substring, not as two lists of strings.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to do that in a performance-critical environment, so I benchmarked all the possible variants I could find and think of with Python 3.11. Here are the results:

```py
words =['test', 'èk', 'user_me', '<markup>', '[^1]']

def find_words(words):
    for word in words:
        if "_" in word or "<" in word or ">" in word or "^" in word:
            pass

def find_words_2(words):
    for word in words:
        for elem in [">", "<", "_", "^"]:
            if elem in word:
                pass

def find_words_3(words):
    for word in words:
        if re.search(r"\_|\<|\>|\^", word):
            pass

def find_words_4(words):
    for word in words:
        if re.match(r"\S*(\_|\<|\>|\^)\S*", word):
            pass

def find_words_5(words):
    for word in words:
        if any(elem in word for elem in [">", "<", "_", "^"]):
            pass

def find_words_6(words):
    for word in words:
        if any(map(word.__contains__, [">", "<", "_", "^"])):
            pass
```

```py
> %timeit find_words(words)
351 ns ± 6.24 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit find_words_2(words)
689 ns ± 15.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit find_words_3(words)
2.42 µs ± 43.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

> %timeit find_words_4(words)
2.75 µs ± 146 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

> %timeit find_words_5(words)
2.65 µs ± 176 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

> %timeit find_words_6(words)
1.64 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

1. The naive chained `or` approach wins (function 1)
2. The basic iteration over each element to test (function 2) is at least 50% faster than using `any()`, and even a regex search is faster than the basic `any()` without `map()`, so I don't get why it exists at all. Not to mention, the syntax is purely algorithmic so any programmer will understand what it does, even without Python background.
3. `re.match()` only searches for patterns starting at the beginning of the line (which is confusing if you come from PHP/Perl regex), so to make it work like PHP/Perl, you need to use `re.search()` or to tweak the regex to include characters before, which comes with a performance penalty.

If the list of substrings to search for is known at programming time, the ugly chained `or` is definitely the way to go. Otherwise, use the basic `for` loop over the list of substrings to search. `any()` and regex are a loss of time in this context.

For a more down-to-earth application (searching if a file is an image by looking for its extension in a list):

```py
def is_image(word: str ) -> bool:
  if  ".bmp" in word or \
      ".jpg" in word or \
      ".jpeg" in word or \
      ".jpe" in word or \
      ".jp2" in word or \
      ".j2c" in word or \
      ".j2k" in word or \
      ".jpc" in word or \
      ".jpf" in word or \
      ".jpx" in word or \
      ".png" in word or \
      ".ico" in word or \
      ".svg" in word or \
      ".webp" in word or \
      ".heif" in word or \
      ".heic" in word or \
      ".tif" in word or \
      ".tiff" in word or \
      ".hdr" in word or \
      ".exr" in word or \
      ".ppm" in word or \
      ".pfm" in word or \
      ".nef" in word or \
      ".rw2" in word or \
      ".cr2" in word or \
      ".cr3" in word or \
      ".crw" in word or \
      ".dng" in word or \
      ".raf" in word or \
      ".arw" in word or \
      ".srf" in word or \
      ".sr2" in word or \
      ".iiq" in word or \
      ".3fr" in word or \
      ".dcr" in word or \
      ".ari" in word or \
      ".pef" in word or \
      ".x3f" in word or \
      ".erf" in word or \
      ".raw" in word or \
      ".rwz" in word:
    return True
  return False

IMAGE_PATTERN = re.compile(r"\.(bmp|jpg|jpeg|jpe|jp2|j2c|j2k|jpc|jpf|jpx|png|ico|svg|webp|heif|heic|tif|tiff|hdr|exr|ppm|pfm|nef|rw2|cr2|cr3|crw|dng|raf|arw|srf|sr2|iiq|3fr|dcr|ari|pef|x3f|erf|raw|rwz)")

extensions = [".bmp", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".jpe", ".jp2", ".j2c", ".j2k", ".jpc", ".jpf", ".jpx", ".png", ".ico", ".svg", ".webp", ".heif", ".heic", ".tif", ".tiff", ".hdr", ".exr", ".ppm", ".pfm", ".nef", ".rw2", ".cr2", ".cr3", ".crw", ".dng", ".raf", ".arw", ".srf", ".sr2", ".iiq", ".3fr", ".dcr", ".ari", ".pef", ".x3f", ".erf", ".raw", ".rwz"]
```

(Note that the extensions are declared in the same order in all variants).

```py
> %timeit is_image("DSC_blablabla_001256.nef") # found
536 ns ± 18.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit is_image("DSC_blablabla_001256.noop") # not found
923 ns ± 43.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit IMAGE_PATTERN.search("DSC_blablabla_001256.nef")
221 ns ± 24.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit IMAGE_PATTERN.search("DSC_blablabla_001256.noop") # not found
207 ns ± 4.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit any(ext in "DSC_blablabla_001256.nef" for ext in extensions) # found
1.53 µs ± 30.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

> %timeit any(ext in "DSC_blablabla_001256.noop" for ext in extensions) # not found
2.2 µs ± 25.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

With a lot more options to test, regex are actually faster and more legible (for once…) than the chained `or`. `any()` ist still the worst.

Empiric tests show that the performance threshold is at 9 elements to test:

- below 9 elements, chained `or` is faster,
- above 9 elements, regex `search()` is faster,
- at exactly 9 elements, both run around 225 ns.

Comment: Which of these allow you to know which word was found?

Answer (score 2):

Just some more info on how to get all list elements availlable in String

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str = "a123" 
list(filter(lambda x:  x in str, a))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want exact matches of words then consider word tokenizing the target string.  I use the recommended word_tokenize from [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html):

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

Here is the tokenized string from the accepted answer:

```
a_string = "A string is more than its parts!"
tokens = word_tokenize(a_string)
tokens
Out[46]: ['A', 'string', 'is', 'more', 'than', 'its', 'parts', '!']
```

The accepted answer gets modified as follows:

```
matches_1 = ["more", "wholesome", "milk"]
[x in tokens for x in matches_1]
Out[42]: [True, False, False]
```

As in the accepted answer, the word "more" is still matched. If "mo" becomes a match string, however, the accepted answer still finds a match.  That is a behavior I did not want.

```
matches_2 = ["mo", "wholesome", "milk"]
[x in a_string for x in matches_1]
Out[43]: [True, False, False]
```

Using word tokenization, "mo" is no longer matched:

```
[x in tokens for x in matches_2]
Out[44]: [False, False, False]
```

That is the additional behavior that I wanted.  This answer also responds to the duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271478/check-list-of-words-in-another-string).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the  context 
suppose if you want to check single literal like(any single word a,e,w,..etc) **in** is enough

```
original_word ="hackerearcth"
for 'h' in original_word:
      print("YES")
```

if you want to check any of the character among the original_word:
make use of

```
if any(your_required in yourinput for your_required in original_word ):
```

if you want all the input you want in that  original_word,make use of all
simple

```
original_word = ['h', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h']
yourinput = str(input()).lower()
if all(requested_word in yourinput for requested_word in original_word):
    print("yes")
```

Comment: What would be yourinput? I can recognise two things: the sentence where I'm looking for something. The array of words I'm looking for. But you describe three variables and I can't get what the third one is.

Answer (score 1):

```
flog = open('test.txt', 'r')
flogLines = flog.readlines()
strlist = ['SUCCESS', 'Done','SUCCESSFUL']
res = False
for line in flogLines:
     for fstr in strlist:
         if line.find(fstr) != -1:
            print('found') 
            res = True


if res:
    print('res true')
else: 
    print('res false')
```

[image: output example image]

Comment: Don't add screenshots, your code is proof enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this kind of function for speed:

```
def check_string(string, substring_list):
    for substring in substring_list:
        if substring in string:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution with set. using `set.intersection`. For a one-liner.

```
subset = {"some" ,"words"} 
text = "some words to be searched here"
if len(subset & set(text.split())) == len(subset):
   print("All values present in text")

if subset & set(text.split()):
   print("Atleast one values present in text")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this question from a link from another closed question:
[Python: How to check a string for substrings from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122079/python-how-to-check-a-string-for-substrings-from-a-list) but don't see an explicit solution to that question in the above answers.

Given a list of substrings and a list of strings, return a unique list of strings that have any of the substrings.

```
substrings = ['hello','world','python']
strings = ['blah blah.hello_everyone','this is a-crazy_world.here',
       'one more string','ok, one more string with hello world python']
# one-liner
list(set([strings_of_interest for strings_of_interest in strings for substring in substrings if substring in strings_of_interest]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = "firstName and favoriteFood"
mandatory_fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']


# for each
for field in mandatory_fields:
    if field not in data:
        print("Error, missing req field {0}".format(field));

# still fine, multiple if statements
if ('firstName' not in data or 
    'lastName' not in data or
    'age' not in data):
    print("Error, missing a req field");

# not very readable, list comprehension
missing_fields = [x for x in mandatory_fields if x not in data]
if (len(missing_fields)>0):
    print("Error, missing fields {0}".format(", ".join(missing_fields)));
```