# Check to ensure a string does not contain multiple values

Tags: python, algorithm, string

**Note- I will not just be testing at the end of a string-- need to locate particular substrings anywhere in the string

What is the fastest way to check to make sure a string does not contain multiple values.  My current method is inefficient and unpythonic:

```
if string.find('png') ==-1 and sring.find('jpg') ==-1 and string.find('gif') == -1 and string.find('YouTube') == -1:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you're testing just the end of the string, remember that str.endswith can accept a tuple.

```
>>> "test.png".endswith(('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))
True
```

otherwise:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('jpg|png|gif').search('testpng.txt')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb74a46e8>
>>> re.compile('jpg|png|gif').search('testpg.txt')
```

Comment: not just testing the end of a string :-( need to detect if these substrings appear anywhere.

Comment: OK, then a regex is probably better; will modify answer

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
if not any(extension in string for extension in ('jpg', 'png', 'gif')):
```

which is basically the same as your code, but more elegantly written.

Answer (score -4):

You could also do something like this if the values to test for didn't need to be managed by a tuple/list.

```
>>> ('png' or 'jpg' or 'foo') in 'testpng.txt'
True
>>> ('png' or 'jpg' or 'foo') in 'testpg.txt'
False
```

EDIT
I see the error of my ways now, it only checks the first.

```
>>> ('bees' or 'png' or 'jpg' or 'foo') in 'testpng.txt'
False
```

Comment: That doesn't work - the `'jpg' or 'png' or...` evaluates to `True`, which is then negated - you are testing for the presence of `False` in the string.

Comment: That *still* won't work: the `or` also converts the strings into booleans; you are now simply testing for `True` in the string.