# Python check if any items of a tuple are in a string

Tags: python, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)
>   [Check to ensure a string does not contain multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542801/check-to-ensure-a-string-does-not-contain-multiple-values)

So guys. If i have

```
example = "1", "2", "3"
```

How would i check if any of the items are in a string.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(s in some_string for s in example):
    # at least one of the elements is a substring of some_string
```

Comment: This looks like the most "Pythonic" way of doing it.

Comment: What would "s" be in your code.
(Fairly new to python.)

Comment: @user1705279: It’s the variable in the generator expression. It represents every string in the `example` tuple.

Comment: networks = (
        ("AAA", "AAA"),
        ("BBB", "BBB"),
    )


some_string="AAA"
for item in networks:
  if some_string in item:
    print "Yes"
    break

Answer (score -2):

One example:

```
>>> example = "1", 2, "3"
>>> str in [type(entry) for entry in example]
```

will return True if there was an str in the tuple.

Comment: I think the question was to check whether they’re in a string, not whether any of them is a string.