# Simplify python code for txt searching

Tags: python, text

I am a beginner at python and I need to check the presence of a given set of string in a huge txt file. I've written this code so far and it runs with no problems on a light subsample of my database. The problem is that it takes more than 10 hours when searching through the whole database and I'm looking for a way to speed up the process.

The code so far reads a list of strings from a txt I've put together (list.txt) and search for every item in every line of the database (hugedataset.txt). My final output should be a list of items which are present in the database (or, alternatively, a list of items which are NOT present). I bet there is a more efficient way to do things though...

Thank you for your support!

```
import re
fobj_in = open('hugedataset.txt')
present=[]

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [line.strip() for line in f]

print list1  

for l in fobj_in:
    for title in list1:
       if title in l:
          print title
          present.append(title)

set=set(presenti)   
print set
```

Comment: Do you need any per-line information?  If all you need to know is whether each item is there or not, couldn't you search the whole database as a single string rather than breaking it up line-by-line?

Comment: No actually I don't need a per-line information, all I need is to know if and which strings are already there..

Comment: Since you only need to know which words are present, don't keep a list and `append` to it, then converting it to a set at the end. That means you have to keep track of a (potentially huge) list, wasting memory. Instead keep a `set` and `add` to it.

Comment: You should also eliminate any extraneous console output in the middle of a tight loop. If there's an actual terminal displaying each title, you could see serious performance issues.

Comment: I should also point out that since you are only looking for the presence of a title, once you find it the first time, you never need to look for it again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need any per-line information, you can search the whole thing in one go for each string:

```
data = open('hugedataset.txt').read()  # Assuming it fits in memory
present=[]  # As @svk points out, you could make this a set

with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    list1 = [line.strip() for line in f]

print list1  

for title in list1:
   if title in data:
      print title
      present.append(title)

set=set(present)   
print set
```

Comment: @user2447387 Your huge data set fit in all in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regexp to check for all substring with a single pass. Look for example at this answer: [Check to ensure a string does not contain multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542801/check-to-ensure-a-string-does-not-contain-multiple-values)