# How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison, match, boolean-logic

I'm trying to make a function that will compare multiple variables to an integer and output a string of three letters. I was wondering if there was a way to translate this into Python. So say:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
mylist = []

if x or y or z == 0:
    mylist.append("c")
if x or y or z == 1:
    mylist.append("d")
if x or y or z == 2:
    mylist.append("e")
if x or y or z == 3: 
    mylist.append("f")
```

which would return a list of:

```
["c", "d", "f"]
```

Comment: use `1` in (tuple)

Comment: When you want to evaluate a list of statements in a any/all manner you can use `any`/`all` functions.
For example:
`all([1, 2, 3, 4, False])` will return False
`all([True, 1, 2, 3])` will return True
`any([False, 0, 0, False])` will return False
`any([False, 0, True, False])` will return True

Comment: I did a summary post based on answers here:

https://medium.com/codervlogger/python-how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value-7338857b1fec

Comment: This question is a very popular duplicate target, but I think it's suboptimal for that purpose. Most people try to do something like `if x == 0 or 1:`, which is of course similar to `if x or y == 0:`, but might be a little confusing for newbies nonetheless. Given the sheer volume of *"Why isn't my `x == 0 or 1` working?"* questions, I would much rather use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503/1222951) as our canonical duplicate target for these questions.

Comment: Take extra care when comparing to "falsey" values like `0`, `0.0` or `False`. You can easily write wrong code which gives the "right" answer.

Comment: For the opposite, see [Comparing a string to multiple items in Python](/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python)

Comment: @tripleee this question really conflates two separate aspects: "Why doesn't this work?" and "How should I write it instead?" In the opposite case (comparing a single value to multiple candidates, rather than multiple values to the same candidate), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python answers "How should I write it?". For "Why doesn't it work?", see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20002503 (as Aran-Fey linked).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159313/how-to-test-the-membership-of-multiple-values-in-a-list for testing multiple variables for *membership in a list*.

Answer (score 1125, accepted):

You misunderstand how boolean expressions work; they don't work like an English sentence and guess that you are talking about the same comparison for all names here. You are looking for:

```
if x == 1 or y == 1 or z == 1:
```

`x` and `y` are otherwise evaluated on their own (`False` if `0`, `True` otherwise).

You can shorten that using a containment test against [a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

```
if 1 in (x, y, z):
```

or better still:

```
if 1 in {x, y, z}:
```

using [a `set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to take advantage of the constant-cost membership test (i.e. `in` takes a fixed amount of time whatever the left-hand operand is).

#### Explanation

When you use `or`, python sees each side of the operator as *separate* expressions. The expression `x or y == 1` is treated as first a boolean test for `x`, then if that is False, the expression `y == 1` is tested.

This is due to [operator precedence](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). The `or` operator has a lower precedence than the `==` test, so the latter is evaluated *first*.

However, even if this were *not* the case, and the expression `x or y or z == 1` was actually interpreted as `(x or y or z) == 1` instead, this would still not do what you expect it to do.

`x or y or z` would evaluate to the first argument that is 'truthy', e.g. not `False`, numeric 0 or empty (see [boolean expressions](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) for details on what Python considers false in a boolean context).

So for the values `x = 2; y = 1; z = 0`, `x or y or z` would resolve to `2`, because that is the first true-like value in the arguments. Then `2 == 1` would be `False`, even though `y == 1` would be `True`.

The same would apply to the inverse; testing multiple values against a single variable; `x == 1 or 2 or 3` would fail for the same reasons. Use `x == 1 or x == 2 or x == 3` or `x in {1, 2, 3}`.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to go for the `set` version.  Tuple's are very cheap to create and iterate over.  On my machine at least, tuples are faster than sets so long as the size of the tuple is around 4-8 elements.  If you have to scan more than that, use a set, but if you are looking for an item out of 2-4 possibilities, a tuple is still faster!  If you can arrange for the most likely case to be first in the tuple, the win is even bigger: (my test: `timeit.timeit('0 in {seq}'.format(seq=tuple(range(9, -1, -1))))`)

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: In Python 3.3 and up, the set is stored as a constant, bypassing the creation time altogether, eliminating the creation time. Tuples *can* be cheap to create as Python caches a bundle of them to avoid memory churn, making that the biggest difference with sets here.

Comment: @dequestarmappartialsetattr: If you time *just* the membership test, for integers sets and tuples are equally fast for the ideal scenario; matching the first element. After that tuples lose out to sets.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Using the `set` literal notation for this test isn't a savings unless the contents of the `set` literal are also literals, right? `if 1 in {x, y, z}:` can't cache the `set`, because `x`, `y` and `z` could change, so either solution needs to build a `tuple` or `set` from scratch, and I suspect whatever lookup savings you might get when checking for membership would be swamped by greater `set` creation time.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: yes, peephole optimisation (be it for `in [...]` or `in {...}`) only works if the contents of the list or set are immutable literals too. Future language updates may change this.

Comment: out of curiosity, i have a list of URLs as strings whereby i'm checking if the string contains multiple substrings (i.e. `'word1' in string and 'word2' in string...`). would the same syntax (i.e. `string in (word1, word2):`) work in this scenario or, as i am expecting, would it fail?

Comment: @Anthony: that's the wrong test; `string` is not contained in the sequence `(word1, word2)`. You can use `all(w in string for w in sequence_of_words_to_test)` if you have multiple words to test in one string. Or use the `word1 in string and word2 in string` approach if you have just 2 or 3 such strings to test, and they are hardcoded.

Comment: `in` is not constant-time "whatever the left-hand operand is" - technically with `set` you'd require at most the time taken to return the hash (calculate it if you didn't cache it) and do an equals check, which can very well take longer than constant time. Although this cost also exists with tuples.

Comment: @Dukeling: 'constant time' is not a fixed quantity. It means the algorithmic complexity is O(1); it doesn't matter how many elements are in the set, containment testing will take the same amount of time, roughly, independently of the size of the set.

Comment: @Dukeling: containment testing against a list or tuple or other sequence takes *linear* time, O(N), as each element is tested one by one. So when the tuple or list or sequence doubles, so does your average time taken. Sets and dictionaries thus beat sequences, especially as the number of elements grows.

Comment: @Dukeling: calculating the hash is a separate O(something) operation, which is independent of the N size of the set, dict, tuple, etc. on the right-hand side. Python immutable types cache the value anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know, but I'm still not sure why you say "whatever the left-hand operand is", because the cost changes depending on which elements you have in the set (even if it's always pseudo-constant) - I'd be fine with that paragraph if you remove that part, or replace it with "regardless of how many elements you have in the set\*".

Comment: @Dukeling: I really don't see a need. Bad hash implementations are the exception, not the norm. We'd have to qualify `listobj[index]` as *O(1) (provided `index` is not a custom Python object with a bad `__index__` implementation)*, or sorting a list as *O(N log N) (provided the contents do not have complex ordering implementations that throw off comparison costs). For `contains` operations, the cost can be assumed to be constant. If the hash cost for a 'bad actor' object is large, it'll still be the same cost independent of the size of the set you test against.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination sure, tuples are faster than sets when comparing 2-3 values, but I would rank an answer imparting good practices from a time complexity perspective much higher than an answer that takes advantage of implementation details (which are subject to change) to achieve microptimizations on the level of "seriously, don't worry about it".

Comment: a) The `set` approach is non-obvious, and there's always the generic pitfall with "falsey" non-integer values: `False in (1,0,2)` and `0.0 in (1,0,2)` both give `True`. b) Aliasing: accidental use of `if x is y` with small integers and [interned strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe) can also give the wrong answer. Are this question and its answers only for integers? c) `in` is overloaded for both strings and sequences; consider: `'77' in '777'` is True, but `'77' in ('666','777')` is False. d)  ...

Comment: d) Subclasses/superclasses: `dict() == collections.Counter()` is True. e) Iterators and ranges: `[0,1,2] == range(3)` is False. Although `[0,1,2] == list(range(3))` is True

Comment: @smci: I don't know what you are getting at here. You are describing normal equality testing rules, sets don't alter those. `False == 0` is also True, and so is `0.0 == 0`. And at least with a set membership test you avoid the sometimes-made `is` error. I'm not saying anything about using `in` on strings or tuples.

Comment: I even found `if 1 in (x, y, z)` slightly faster than `if x == 1 or y == 1 or z == 1`

Answer (score 119):

Your problem is more easily addressed with a dictionary structure like:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
d = {0: 'c', 1:'d', 2:'e', 3:'f'}
mylist = [d[k] for k in [x, y, z]]
```

Comment: Or even `d = "cdef"` which leads to `MyList = ["cdef"[k] for k in [x, y, z]]`

Comment: or `map(lambda i: 'cdef'[i], [x, y, z])`

Comment: Aside from the list comprehension which I'm not yet fully accustomed to, most of us had the same reflex: build that dict !

Answer (score 78):

As stated by Martijn Pieters, the correct, and fastest, format is:

```
if 1 in {x, y, z}:
```

Using his advice you would now have separate if-statements so that Python will read each statement whether the former were `True` or `False`. Such as:

```
if 0 in {x, y, z}:
    mylist.append("c")
if 1 in {x, y, z}:
    mylist.append("d")
if 2 in {x, y, z}:
    mylist.append("e")
...
```

This will work, but *if* you are comfortable using dictionaries (see what I did there), you can clean this up by making an initial dictionary mapping the numbers to the letters you want, then just using a for-loop:

```
num_to_letters = {0: "c", 1: "d", 2: "e", 3: "f"}
for number in num_to_letters:
    if number in {x, y, z}:
        mylist.append(num_to_letters[number])
```

Comment: @VisioN You mean `for number in num_to_letters`? You don't need `.keys()`, dicts iterate over keys by default. Regarding using a string, you mean something like this, right? `for i, c in enumerate('cdef'): if i in {x, y, z}: mylist.append(c)` Agreed, that would be simpler. Or better yet, `s = 'cdef'; mylist = [s[i] for i in [x, y, z]]`

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, you are right, it's my mistake! I completely forgot about the default behaviour. Unfortunately, I cannot edit my comment, so I have deleted it since you have highlighted the better approach in your comment.

Answer (score 55):

The direct way to write `x or y or z == 0` is

```
if any(map((lambda value: value == 0), (x,y,z))):
    pass # write your logic.
```

But I dont think, you like it. :)
And this way is ugly.

The other way (a better) is:

```
0 in (x, y, z)
```

BTW lots of `if`s could be written as something like this

```
my_cases = {
    0: Mylist.append("c"),
    1: Mylist.append("d")
    # ..
}

for key in my_cases:
    if key in (x,y,z):
        my_cases[key]()
        break
```

Comment: In your example of the `dict` instead of a key, you will get errors because the return value of `.append` is `None`, and calling `None` gives an `AttributeError`.  In general I agree with this method, though.

Comment: the dict instead of a key is wrong, you will get Mylist=['c', 'd'] when the dictionary get initialized even if you commented out "for..loop" part

Comment: In your first example `filter` would be better than `map`, as it will return only instances where lambda evaluates to true

Comment: A comprehension is much simpler than a map of a lambda: `any(v == 0 for v in (x, y, z))`

Answer (score 36):

If you ARE very very lazy, you can put the values inside an array. Such as

```
list = []
list.append(x)
list.append(y)
list.append(z)
nums = [add numbers here]
letters = [add corresponding letters here]
for index in range(len(nums)):
    for obj in list:
        if obj == num[index]:
            MyList.append(letters[index])
            break
```

You can also put the numbers and letters in a dictionary and do it, but this is probably a LOT more complicated than simply if statements. That's what you get for trying to be extra lazy :)

One more thing, your

```
if x or y or z == 0:
```

will compile, but not in the way you want it to. When you simply put a variable in an if statement (example)

```
if b
```

the program will check if the variable is not null. Another way to write the above statement (which makes more sense) is

```
if bool(b)
```

Bool is an inbuilt function in python which basically does the command of verifying a boolean statement (If you don't know what that is, it is what you are trying to make in your if statement right now :))

Another lazy way I found is :

```
if any([x==0, y==0, z==0])
```

Comment: -1 There's a lot of bad practice here. `list` is a Python builtin; use another name instead, like `xyz` for example. Why do you construct the list in four steps when you can do one, i.e. `xyz = [x, y, z]`? Don't use parallel lists, use a dict instead. All in all, this solution is much more convoluted than [ThatGuyRussell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32085628/4518341). Also for the last part, why not do a comprehension, i.e. `any(v == 0 for v in (x, y, z))`? Also [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) are something else in Python.

Answer (score 35):

To check if a value is contained within a set of variables you can use the inbuilt modules           `itertools` and `operator`.

For example:

Imports:

```
from itertools import repeat
from operator import contains
```

Declare variables:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
```

Create mapping of values (in the order you want to check):

```
check_values = (0, 1, 3)
```

Use `itertools` to allow repetition of the variables:

```
check_vars = repeat((x, y, z))
```

Finally, use the `map` function to create an iterator:

```
checker = map(contains, check_vars, check_values)
```

Then, when checking for the values (in the original order), use `next()`:

```
if next(checker)  # Checks for 0
    # Do something
    pass
elif next(checker)  # Checks for 1
    # Do something
    pass
```

etc...

This has an advantage over the `lambda x: x in (variables)` because `operator` is an inbuilt module and is faster and more efficient than using `lambda` which has to create a custom in-place function.

Another option for checking if there is a non-zero (or False) value in a list:

```
not (x and y and z)
```

Equivalent:

```
not all((x, y, z))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.  It only covers the first case in the provided example.

Answer (score 34):

Set is the good approach here, because it orders the variables, what seems to be your goal here. `{z,y,x}` is `{0,1,3}` whatever the order of the parameters.

```
>>> ["cdef"[i] for i in {z,x,y}]
['c', 'd', 'f']
```

This way, the whole solution is O(n).

Answer (score 32):

I think this will handle it better:

```
my_dict = {0: "c", 1: "d", 2: "e", 3: "f"}

def validate(x, y, z):
    for ele in [x, y, z]:
        if ele in my_dict.keys():
            return my_dict[ele]
```

Output:

```
print validate(0, 8, 9)
c
print validate(9, 8, 9)
None
print validate(9, 8, 2)
e
```

Answer (score 32):

If you want to use if, else statements following is another solution:

```
myList = []
aList = [0, 1, 3]

for l in aList:
    if l==0: myList.append('c')
    elif l==1: myList.append('d')
    elif l==2: myList.append('e')
    elif l==3: myList.append('f')

print(myList)
```

Answer (score 32):

All of the excellent answers provided here concentrate on the specific requirement of the original poster and concentrate on the `if 1 in {x,y,z}` solution put forward by Martijn Pieters.
What they ignore is the broader implication of the question:
**How do I test one variable against multiple values?**
The solution provided will not work for partial hits if using strings for example:
Test if the string "Wild" is in multiple values

```
>>> x = "Wild things"
>>> y = "throttle it back"
>>> z = "in the beginning"
>>> if "Wild" in {x, y, z}: print (True)
...
```

or

```
>>> x = "Wild things"
>>> y = "throttle it back"
>>> z = "in the beginning"
>>> if "Wild" in [x, y, z]: print (True)
...
```

for this scenario it's easiest to convert to a string

```
>>> [x, y, z]
['Wild things', 'throttle it back', 'in the beginning']
>>> {x, y, z}
{'in the beginning', 'throttle it back', 'Wild things'}
>>> 

>>> if "Wild" in str([x, y, z]): print (True)
... 
True
>>> if "Wild" in str({x, y, z}): print (True)
... 
True
```

It should be noted however, as mentioned by `@codeforester`, that word boundries are lost with this method, as in:

```
>>> x=['Wild things', 'throttle it back', 'in the beginning']
>>> if "rot" in str(x): print(True)
... 
True
```

the 3 letters `rot` do exist in combination in the list but not as an individual word. Testing for " rot " would fail but if one of the list items were "rot in hell", that would fail as well.
The upshot being, be careful with your search criteria if using this method and be aware that it does have this limitation.

Answer (score 28):

```
d = {0:'c', 1:'d', 2:'e', 3: 'f'}
x, y, z = (0, 1, 3)
print [v for (k,v) in d.items() if x==k or y==k or z==k]
```

Answer (score 28):

This code may be helpful

```
L ={x, y, z}
T= ((0,"c"),(1,"d"),(2,"e"),(3,"f"),)
List2=[]
for t in T :
if t[0] in L :
    List2.append(t[1])
    break;
```

Answer (score 17):

You can try the method shown below. In this method, you will have the freedom to specify/input the number of variables that you wish to enter.

```
mydict = {0:"c", 1:"d", 2:"e", 3:"f"}
mylist= []

num_var = int(raw_input("How many variables? ")) #Enter 3 when asked for input.

for i in range(num_var): 
    ''' Enter 0 as first input, 1 as second input and 3 as third input.'''
    globals()['var'+str('i').zfill(3)] = int(raw_input("Enter an integer between 0 and 3 "))
    mylist += mydict[globals()['var'+str('i').zfill(3)]]

print mylist
>>> ['c', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 12):

One line solution:

```
mylist = [{0: 'c', 1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}[i] for i in [0, 1, 2, 3] if i in (x, y, z)]
```

Or:

```
mylist = ['cdef'[i] for i in range(4) if i in (x, y, z)]
```

Answer (score 10):

The most pythonic way of representing your pseudo-code in Python would be:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
mylist = []

if any(v == 0 for v in (x, y, z)):
    mylist.append("c")
if any(v == 1 for v in (x, y, z)):
    mylist.append("d")
if any(v == 2 for v in (x, y, z)):
    mylist.append("e")
if any(v == 3 for v in (x, y, z)):
    mylist.append("f")
```

Comment: This approach is more universal than ` if 2 in (x, y, z): mylist.append('e')` because allows arbitrary comparisons (e.g. `if any(v >= 42 for v in (x, y, z)):` ).  And performance of all 3 methods (`2 in {x,y,z}`, `2 in (x,y,z)`, `any(_v == 2 for _v in (x,y,z))`) seems to be almost the same in CPython3.6 (see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/imposeren/06eb52771d1b779e64d9bef525da87d8))

Answer (score 10):

Maybe you need direct formula for output bits set.

```
x=0 or y=0 or z=0   is equivalent to x*y*z = 0

x=1 or y=1 or z=1   is equivalent to (x-1)*(y-1)*(z-1)=0

x=2 or y=2 or z=2   is equivalent to (x-2)*(y-2)*(z-2)=0
```

Let's map to bits: `'c':1 'd':0xb10 'e':0xb100 'f':0xb1000`

Relation of isc (is 'c'):

```
if xyz=0 then isc=1 else isc=0
```

Use math if formula https://youtu.be/KAdKCgBGK0k?list=PLnI9xbPdZUAmUL8htSl6vToPQRRN3hhFp&t=315

[c]: `(xyz=0 and isc=1) or (((xyz=0 and isc=1) or (isc=0)) and (isc=0))`

[d]: `((x-1)(y-1)(z-1)=0 and isc=2) or (((xyz=0 and isd=2) or (isc=0)) and (isc=0))`

...

Connect these formulas by following logic:

- logic `and` is the sum of squares of equations
- logic `or` is the product of equations

and you'll have a total equation
express sum and you have total formula of sum

then sum&1 is c, sum&2 is d, sum&4 is e, sum&5 is f

After this you may form predefined array where index of string elements would correspond to ready string.

`array[sum]` gives you the string.

Answer (score 8):

It can be done easily as

```
for value in [var1,var2,var3]:
     li.append("targetValue")
```

Answer (score 7):

To test multiple variables with one single value: `if 1 in {a,b,c}:`

To test multiple values with one variable: `if a in {1, 2, 3}:`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're building some kind of Caesar cipher.

A much more generalized approach is this:

```
input_values = (0, 1, 3)
origo = ord('c')
[chr(val + origo) for val in inputs]
```

outputs

```
['c', 'd', 'f']
```

Not sure if it's a desired side effect of your code, but the order of your output will always be sorted.

If this is what you want, the final line can be changed to:

```
sorted([chr(val + origo) for val in inputs])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use dictionary :

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
list=[]
dict = {0: 'c', 1: 'd', 2: 'e', 3: 'f'}
if x in dict:
    list.append(dict[x])
else:
    pass

if y in dict:
    list.append(dict[y])
else:
    pass
if z in dict:
    list.append(dict[z])
else:
    pass

print list
```

Comment: This may append same more then once this. Set?

Answer (score 4):

Without dict, try this solution:

```
x, y, z = 0, 1, 3    
offset = ord('c')
[chr(i + offset) for i in (x,y,z)]
```

and gives:

```
['c', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help you.

```
def test_fun(val):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    z = 2
    myList = []
    if val in (x, y, z) and val == 0:
        myList.append("C")
    if val in (x, y, z) and val == 1:
        myList.append("D")
    if val in (x, y, z) and val == 2:
        myList.append("E")

test_fun(2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can unite this

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
```

in one variable.

```
In [1]: xyz = (0,1,3,) 
In [2]: mylist = []
```

Change our conditions as:

```
In [3]: if 0 in xyz: 
    ...:     mylist.append("c") 
    ...: if 1 in xyz: 
    ...:     mylist.append("d") 
    ...: if 2 in xyz: 
    ...:     mylist.append("e") 
    ...: if 3 in xyz:  
    ...:     mylist.append("f")
```

Output:

```
In [21]: mylist                                                                                
Out[21]: ['c', 'd', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3):

you can develop it through two ways

```
    def compareVariables(x,y,z):
        mylist = []
        if x==0 or y==0 or z==0:
            mylist.append('c')
        if  x==1 or y==1 or z==1:
            mylist.append('d')
        if  x==2 or y==2 or z==2:
            mylist.append('e')
        if  x==3 or y==3 or z==3:
            mylist.append('f')
        else:
            print("wrong input value!")
        print('first:',mylist)

        compareVariables(1, 3, 2)
```

Or

```
    def compareVariables(x,y,z):
        mylist = []
        if 0 in (x,y,z):
             mylist.append('c')
        if 1 in (x,y,z):
             mylist.append('d')
        if 2 in (x,y,z):
             mylist.append('e')
        if 3 in (x,y,z):
             mylist.append('f')
        else:
             print("wrong input value!")
        print('second:',mylist)

        compareVariables(1, 3, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `or` does not work like that, as [explained by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002504/918959).

While the generic answer would be use

```
if 0 in (x, y, z):
    ...
```

this is not the best one for the *specific* problem. In your case you're doing *repeated tests*, therefore it is worthwhile to compose a *set* of these variables:

```
values = {x, y, z}

if 0 in values:
    mylist.append("c")

if 1 in values:
    mylist.append("d")
```

We can simplify this using a dictionary - this will result in the same values:

```
mappings = {0: "c", 1: "d", ...}
for k in mappings:
    if k in values:
        mylist.append(mappings[k])
```

Or if the ordering of the `mylist` is arbitrary, you can loop over the *values* instead and match them to the mappings:

```
mappings = {0: "c", 1: "d", ...}
for v in (x, y, z):
    if v in mappings:
        mylist.append(mappings[v])
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

While the pattern for testing multiple values

```
>>> 2 in {1, 2, 3}
True
>>> 5 in {1, 2, 3}
False
```

is very readable and is working in many situation, there is one pitfall:

```
>>> 0 in {True, False}
True
```

But we want to have

```
>>> (0 is True) or (0 is False)
False
```

#### Solution

One generalization of the previous expression is based on the answer from [ytpillai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30430962/5599281):

```
>>> any([0 is True, 0 is False])
False
```

which can be written as

```
>>> any(0 is item for item in (True, False))
False
```

While this expression returns the right result it is not as readable as the first expression :-(

Answer (score 1):

To test multiple variables against a single value:

Wrap the variables in a set object, e.g. {a, b, c}.
Use the in operator to test if the value is stored in any of the variables.
The in operator will return True if the value is stored in at least one of the variables.

```py
# ✅ test multiple variables against single value using tuple

if 'a' in (a, b, c):
    print('value is stored in at least one of the variables')

# ---------------------------------------------------------

# ✅ test multiple variables against single value using tuple

if 'a' in {a, b, c}:
    print('value is stored in at least one of the variables')

# ---------------------------------------------------------


# ✅ test multiple variables against single value (OR operator chaining)
if a == 'a' or b == 'a' or c == 'a':
    print('value is stored in at least one of the variables')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do it:

```
x = 0
y = 1
z = 3
mylist = []

if any(i in [0] for i in[x,y,z]):
    mylist.append("c")
if any(i in [1] for i in[x,y,z]):
    mylist.append("d")
if any(i in [2] for i in[x,y,z]):
    mylist.append("e")
if any(i in [3] for i in[x,y,z]):
    mylist.append("f")
```

It is a mix of **list comprehension** and **any** keyword.

Comment: Why `i in [0]` instead of just `i == 0`?

Comment: For a single comparison like in this question, you can use "==" but if you want multiple comparisons with multiple variables, then you can use the "in" operator like: if any(i in [0,5,4,9,7] for i in[x,y,z] )

Answer (score 0):

**usage without if example:**

```
x,y,z = 0,1,3
values = {0:"c",1:"d",2:"e",3:"f"} # => as if usage
my_list = [values[i] for i in (x,y,z)]

print(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRST, A CORRECTION TO THE `OR` CONDITIONAL:

You need to say:

```
if x == 0 or y == 0 or z == 0:
```

The reason is that "or" splits up the condition into separate logical parts. The way your original statement was written, those parts were:

```
x
y
z == 0   // or 1, 2, 3 depending on the if statement
```

The last part was fine --- checking to see if z == 0, for instance --- but the first two parts just said essentially `if x` and `if y`. Since integers always evaluate to `True` unless they're 0, that means the first part of your condition was always `True` when `x` or `y` didn't equal 0 (which in the case of y was always, since you had `y = 1`, causing your whole condition (because of how `OR` works) to always be `True`.

To avoid that, you need to make sure all parts of your condition (each side of the `OR`) make sense on their own (you can do that by pretending that the other side(s) of the `OR` statement doesn't exist). That's how you can confirm whether or not your `OR` condition is correctly defined.

You would write the statements individually like so:

```
if x == 0
if y == 0
if z == 0
```

which means the correct mergin with the `OR` keyword would be:

```
if x == 0 or y == 0 or z == 0
```

SECOND, HOW TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM:

You're basically wanting to check to see if any of the variables match a given integer and if so, assign it a letter that matches it in a one-to-one mapping. You want to do that for a certain list of integers so that the output is a list of letters. You'd do that like this:

```
def func(x, y, z):

    result = []

    for integer, letter in zip([0, 1, 2, 3], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']):
        if x == integer or y == integer or z == integer:
            result.append(letter)
            
    return result
```

Similarly, you could use LIST COMPREHENSION to achieve the same result faster:

```
def func(x, y, z):

    return [ 
                letter 
                for integer, letter in zip([0, 1, 2, 3], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
                if x == integer or y == integer or z == integer
           ]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#selection
: a=np.array([0,1,3])                                                                                                                                                 

#options
: np.diag(['c','d','e','f']) 
array([['c', '', '', ''],
       ['', 'd', '', ''],
       ['', '', 'e', ''],
       ['', '', '', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

now we can use **a** as [row,col] selector, which acts as if any(...) condition :

```
#list of options[sel,sel]
: np.diag(['c','d','e','f'])[a,a]                                                                                                                                     

 array(['c', 'd', 'f'], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: I don't think the question is asking about numpy