# Avoid repeating variable when comparing it to different characters (x == a or x == b or x==...)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like in the following code; how do I avoid repeating "char =="?

```
for char in s:
    if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' or char == 'o' or char == 'u':
        do...
```

Is it possible to approximate the second line to what one would say in natural language: "if char is equal to a, e, i, o, or u..." ?

Comment: `if char in "aeiou"`

Comment: Oh!  wasn't it simple? Thanks a lot Sislam! Wouldn't it be more useful if you put the answer as an answer instead of as comment so that people know is an answer?

Comment: [Comparing a string to multiple items in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6838238/2301450)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in`-operator to check if a `char` exists in a string:

```
if char in "aeiou":
    #Do something
```

Comment: So you can make the characters into a string and not only avoids repeating the variable, but also  " == " and "or"!  Supernice and simple!