# Very simple code, not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to elicit two responses depending on user input, and can't get it to work. It just keeps printing `"Correct, seems you're smarter than I thought..."`. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

```
print ("Welcome to UTOPIA")


river= ""
while not river:
    river = input ("\n\n\n\nYou come across a raging river, what do you do? ")

if river == "swim" or "swim through it":
    print ("Correct, seems you're smarter than I thought...")

elif river == "walk through it" or "walk through":
    print ("You cant walk through such a big river... silly!")

else:
    print ("Well, sensible suggestions now...")
```

Comment: your `if river == "swim" or "swim through it":` is always true, due to the way `or` works in python.

Comment: you need to do `or river == "swim through it"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing a string to multiple items in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python)

Comment: note that `if "swim through it":` will always be seen as true as it is not an empty string.

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Answer (score 2):

The issue has to do with your if statements. An or will not automatically look at the last variable used so it must be specified again. If "some string" will always evaluate to true as long as the string isn't empty.

```
print ("Welcome to UTOPIA")

river= ""
while not river:
    river = input ("\n\n\n\nYou come across a raging river, what do you do? ")

if river == "swim" or river == "swim through it": #Notice the change
    print ("Correct, seems you're smarter than I thought...")

elif river == "walk through it" or river == "walk through": #Notice the change
    print ("You cant walk through such a big river... silly!")

else:
    print ("Well, sensible suggestions now...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're doing

```
if river == "swim" or "swim through it":
    # ...
```

which is not correct code.
Essentially you're saying "If river is swim or string "swim through it" " which doesn't make sense.

You're looking for

```
if river == "swim" or river == "swim through it"
```

Answer (score 0):

All non-empty strings are (unfortunately) `True` in Python.

That means that this will always be `True`:

```
if something or "string":
```

Because `or "string"` will always be `True`.

Comment: except an empty string ;)