# Comparing a string with multiple substrings of another string

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

Is there another simpler way to write code that basically checks every character of the string `'abcde'`

```
if input == 'a' or input == 'ab' or input == 'abc' or input == 'abcd' or input == 'abcde':
    return True
```

Comment: Can they be multiple combinations of "abcde" ? Like `input=='de'` ?

Comment: Related: [Comparing a string to multiple items in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6838238/7851470)

Comment: Please don't use `input` as your variable names.

Answer (score 37):

This should do the same thing as what you put.

```
return 'abcde'.startswith(input)
```

Comment: From the description, it's not clear what the result for the empty string should be, `"abcde".startswith("") == True`, which doesn't quite match the example code

Comment: Yeah, if you want to not include empty strings, I think the best thing would be adding an `and input`.

Answer (score 12):

Don't name variables `input`, since it will shadow the builtin function [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). Its considered bad practice to do this, and easy enough to just choose another variable name.

You could use a set to check if the input matches any of the substrings:

```
lookups = {'a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde'}

my_input = input()

if my_input in lookups:
    return True
```

We could also generate this set using a set comprehension:

```
characters = 'abcde'

lookups = {characters[:i] for i in range(1, len(characters) + 1)}

my_input = input()

if my_input in lookups:
    return True
```

For large sets of combinations, the benefit of using a set over a list is that you get constant time **O(1)** lookups for searching. This is much better than using a list, which will give you linear **O(N)** lookups.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple cute ways to do it. 
`startwith` is probably the most efficient one, but these should work too:

using `lstrip`:

```
return 'abcde'.lstrip(input)!='abcde'
```

using `list comprehension`:

```
return any(['abcde'[:i+1] == input for i in range(len('abcde'))])
```

using `regex`:

```
   pattern = re.compile('^'+input)
   return bool(pattern.match('abcde'))
```

or just:

```
  return 'abcde'[:len(input)]==input
```

Comment: What is `not not pattern.match(...)`? If you did it just to convert match to a bool you could use `bool` directly: `bool(pattern.match(...))`

Answer (score 5):

You could probably try something like this:

```py
def your_function():
    # Add as much chars that you want here
    chars = "abcde"

    # Assuming you are taking the user input from terminal
    user_input = input()

    # Loop over every substring from chars
    for i in range(len(chars) + 1):
        if chars[:i] == user_input:
            return True

    return False
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
If input in ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde']:
    return True
else:
   return False
```