# How can I check if a var is one of 2 strings in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this code, I want to check if the user typed the URL with "http" in it and after that, check if the SSL var is http or https, but I want it to ignore the caps (http or HTTP)

```
SSL = input(" Does your site have (http) or (https)? >> ")
URL = input(" Your URL >> ")
if "http" not in URL:
    if SSL == "http":  # I want SSL to be http or HTTP
        print("I work!")
```

Comment: `SSL.lower() == 'http'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing a string to multiple items in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python)

Comment: Or `SSL in ['http', 'HTTP']` if you don't want to allow things like `hTtP`

Comment: BTW: it can begood to use `strip()` to remove spaces which someone would type accidently and it may not see them on screen. `SSL.strip().lower() == 'http'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
if SSL in ('http', 'HTTP'):
```

for arbitrary lists of values or

```
if SSL.lower() == 'http':
```

for case insensitivity (but note that `"hTTp"` will also match in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lower()` method:

```
SSL = input(" Does your site have (http) or (https)? >> ")
URL = input(" Your URL >> ")
if "http" not in URL:
    if SSL.lower() == "http":  # I want SSL to be http or HTTP
        print("I work!")
```