# Telegram bot replies even on random texts

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am creating a Telegram bot which would reply `Hello` in random languages. Is working fine but the problem is it replies even when I send something randomly with no meaning like `sfdsfjls`.

What should I do so that it replies only when I say `Hi` or `Hello` and reply something like `I don't get it` when I send something random.

I am using `pytelegrambotapi`.

[image]

My code:

```py
import telebot
import random

bot_token =''

bot= telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

lang1= ['Hola','Konnichiwa','Bonjour','Namaste']

# Handle normal messages
@bot.message_handler()
def send_welcome(message):

# Detect 'hi'
    if message.text == 'hi' or 'hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (random.choice(lang1)))
```

Comment: Hi. Please remove the tags for `python-telegram-bot` and `php-telegram-bot`. The former is a different python library and the latter clearly is inappropriate because you're using python. Instead use the tag `py-telegram-bot-api` which is for the library that you use ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need

```py
if message.text == 'hi' or message.text == 'hello':
```

Instead off

```py
if message.text == 'hi' or 'hello':
```

Because the `or 'hello'` part will **always** result in `TRUE` as you can [test here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/vyS1uETBVkE9EQQyMtW5MtMUIGJAQSBfIb8ISKfm5OSrW3FxFhRl5pVoqEemFqtr/v8PAA).

---

Another option, tho check [if a string matches any other string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838238/comparing-a-string-to-multiple-items-in-python) could look something like this:

```py
triggers = {'hi', 'hello'}
if message.text in triggers:
```

---

Applying those fixes, and adding a additional check [based on the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68176365/telegram-bot-replies-even-on-random-texts/68177580?noredirect=1#comment120498519_68177580) gives us the following code:

```py
import telebot
import random

bot_token =''

bot= telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

lang1= ['Hola','Konnichiwa','Bonjour','Namaste']

# Handle normal messages
@bot.message_handler()
def send_welcome(message):

# Detect Messages
if message.text == 'hi' or message.text == 'hello':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, (random.choice(lang1)))
elif message.text == 'Test':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Test succeeded')
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Sorry I don\'t get it!')
```

Comment: Great I got it! But one thing is still not cleared that what should I do to make the bot reply ' Sorry I don't get it!' when typing anything random.

Comment: Please see my edit. Using a `if`, `elif` and `else` should be enough.