# I tried to make a menu which accepts items and asks if you want to add anything else to it. But it accepts items not on the menu

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
print("welcome to our shop")
a=input("what is your name \n")
print("good morning "+a+" hope you are having a great day")
print("here is the menu")
menu="coffee,tea,biriyani,noodles,soup" 
print(menu) 
ccoffee=20
ctea=15
cbiriyani=100
cnoodles=125
csoup=40
b=input("what would u like from this \n")
if b=="coffee" or "tea" or "biriyani" or "noodles" or "soup":  
    print("ok, would you like anything more")
    p=input("yes or no \n")
    if p=="yes":
        input("what else \n")
         if input=="tea" or "biriyani" or "noodles" or "soup" or "coffee":
           print("ok")
        else:
           print("we dont have that")
    else:
        print("your order will be ready soon")
        input("would you like anything more \n")
        p=input("yes or no \n")
        if p=="yes":
          input("what else \n")
          if input=="tea"or"biriyani"or"noodles"or"soup":
            print("ok")
          else:
            print("we do not have that sorry")
        else:
          print("your order will be ready soon")`print("welcome to our shop")
```

I tried to make it so that it won't accept items not on the menu but it accept it for some reason (I'm guessing the `or` operator doesn't work the way I intend it to). How do I fix this?

Comment: `input=="tea" or "biriyani" or "noodles" or "soup" or "coffee"` is **always** going to be truth-y, because even if `input != "tea"` then the expression evaluates to `"biriyani"`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/6838238/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator is not used correctly , you need to compare `b` to all the options  here is the correct way :

```py
if b=="coffee" or b=="tea" or b=="biriyani" or b=="noodles" or b=="soup":
   #your code
```

a better way to do it using `in` :

```py
options = ["coffee", "tea", "biriyani", "noodles", "soup"]

if b in options:
   #your code
```

For the second condition store the input in a new variable `additional` and do the same :

```py
    if p=="yes":
         additional =input("what else \n")
         if additional in options:
           print("ok")
```