# Combining multiple membership tests

Tags: python, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

To check if a string contains a substring, one can use "in" like so:

```
if "abc" in str:
    print("yay")
```

And to check if a string contains one of two substrings one can use "or" like so:

```
if "abc" in str or "def" in str:
    print("yay")
```

My question is whether or not python has a way to simplify that into something like this:

```
if "abc" or "def" in str:
    print("yay")
```

I know this won't work as intended because it will always evaluate to true. (Python will check for at least one of the two statements, either

- "abc"
- "def" in str

being true and "abc" will always evaluate to true)

Having said that, is there anyway to check for such a condition other than this, rather verbose, method:

```
if "abc" in str or "def" in str:
    print("yay")
```

Comment: Are you aware of [regular expressions](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: have you considered using regex? that would allow you to search many strings with the | symbol treating them as 'or'

Comment: The "verbose" method is perfectly reasonable and clear (but you should avoid using built-in names like `str` for your variables).

Answer (score 4):

```
if any(word in sentence for word in {"abc", "def"}):
    print("yay")
```

Answer (score 4):

Put them in an array and do:

```
if any(x in word for x in a):
```

This has been answered here [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: Do not use `str` as a variable name as it is a built-in

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly how to word my google searches when I came across this issue. I didn't know it was already asked. Thanks -- I have flagged the question for deletion as I can no longer do it myself.

Comment: @BhargavRao built in as what? It doesn't matter, this will still compile and work

Comment: [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) in Python has a reserved builtin function. Using that as a variable name will hinder the ability of you using that function. So henceforth please do not use that as a variable name

Comment: It would compile and work, but then good luck trying to cast objects as strings with `str(my_object)`.

Comment: For this example it works is all im saying

Comment: @paulpaul1076 doesn't matter, still a bad practice

Comment: @paulpaul1076 Thanks that was all that was needed. I have reversed my downvote to upvote. Remember this in future.

Comment: "For this example it works" is no justification for code that's liable to blow up in the developer's face.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is like whether there is a way, to check whether any string in given list of strings exist in a bigger string . We can use the `any()` function along with `generator expressions` for that.

Example -

```
>>> s = "Hello World Bye Abcd"
>>> l = ["Hello","Blah"]
>>> l1 = ["Yes","No"]
>>> any(li in s for li in l)
True
>>> any(li in s for li in l1)
False
```

Comment: Just BTW here, but those aren't `list` comprehensions, they're generator expressions.