# if any(x in str for x in a): what's x when true

Tags: python

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string) gets me half way to where I want to go.  I'd like to know which string the following code found, but on my machine it isn't working:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str = "a123"
if any(x in str for x in a):
    print x
```

This produces the error: "NameError: name 'x' is not defined".  How does one determine which string (within `a`) was found?  In other words, based on which string was found in the list, I want to do something specific in the code that follows, thus I need to know what `x` was when the condition was true.  I'm using python 3.5.0

Comment: You can't. You would have to do this in a for loop.

Comment: I'm new to python, but if you're really using 3.5, don't you need to call print as a function, like `print(x)`? I find it strange that you're seeing a NameError; should be a SyntaxError...

Comment: @Frank Is correct, Python 3 always requires brackets with `print` calls. If this is your real code and you're not getting syntax errors, you might actually be running Python 2.

Answer (score 6):

The variable `x` refers to the scope of the [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) passed to the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) function, so you can not `print x` outside of this generator.

`any()` just returns `True` or `False`.

Instead, you might use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next):

```
print next(x for x in a if x in str)
```

And add a default value in the case no correct value is found:

```
s = next((x for x in a if x in str), None)
if s:
    print s
```

---

Just a note: you should not create a variable which is called `str` because [there is a built-in](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str) with the same name. This is considred as bad practice to overwrite it because this can lead to confusion.

Comment: Alternatively set a value: `s = next((x for x in a if x in str), None)` then print if that value exists `if s: print s`

Answer (score 4):

Use `any` when you don't care which condition is true, as long as one of them is. Instead, use a `for` loop (with an optional `else` clause if no `x` was in `str`).

```
for x in a:
    if x in str:
        print x
        break
else:
    print "Nothing in 'a' found in 'str'"
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
print [x for x in a if x in str]
```

Useful in more complicated examples. e.g.

---

for

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str = 'a123c567b'
```

output will be

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

---

for

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
str = 'a1c5c'
```

output will be:

```
['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
string = "a123"
for i in a:
    if i in string:
        print(i)
```