# Python check if string contains all words in Python

Tags: python, string

I want to check if all words are found in another string without any loops or iterations:

```
a = ['god', 'this', 'a']

sentence = "this is a god damn sentence in python"

all(a in sentence)
```

should return `TRUE`.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string

Answer (score 4):

You could use a set depending on your exact needs as follows:

```
a = ['god', 'this', 'a']
sentence = "this is a god damn sentence in python"

print set(a) <= set(sentence.split())
```

This would print `True`, where `<=` is [`issubset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=union#set.issubset).

Comment: You could drop the `' '` to become `set(sentence.split())`

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
all(x in sentence for x in a)
```

Or:

```
>>> chk = list(filter(lambda x: x not in sentence, a)) #Python3, for Python2 no need to convert to list
[] #Will return empty if all words from a are in sentence
>>> if not chk:
        print('All words are in sentence')
```

Comment: That's part of `all` expression...nothing to do about it, but I don't believe that's part of OP concern...as he is avoiding any explicit `for` loop