# Several variables in if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement, logical-operators

This works as intended:

```
if c1 in r':6' or c2 in r':6':
    subst_weight = 1
```

This doesn't:

```
if (c1 or c2) in r':6':
    subst_weight = 1
```

Why and what is the differnce? The goal is to find out whether `c1` or `c2` is in the string.
Same here:

Works:

```
if c1 == '6' or c2 == '6':
```

Doesn't work:

```
if (c1 or c2) == '6':
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `one or two` will return `one` if defined, and `two` if `one` is not truthy, and I don't see a reason it wouldn't work with your logic because if either is truthy, and is contained in string, it will evaluate to `True`

```
>>> a = "6"
>>> b = ":"
>>> (a or b)
'6'
>>> (b or a)
':'
>>> a = None
>>> (a or b)
':'
>>> b
':'
```

For more than 2 variables it will return the first that's truthy

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = None
>>> c = 6
>>> a or b or c
6
```

But note your logic, you want to check if any of the variables is in that string, you can't use this, because the `c1` ca be equal to `"example"` and that's what's gonna be returned to that `if` statement and it's not in `":6"`

Comment: 'defined' in this context means 'truthy'. If c1 is truthy, but not a substring of r':6', the if statement will be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Although not literally answering your question of why, this is an answer to "how then should I..."

```
if any(x in r':6' for x in [c1, c2]):
  something
```

If you ever get more of the 'c's, use a variable to define the list beforehand.

(sauce: [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string))

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Still looks kind of ugly.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
if (c1 or c2) in r':6':
```

Evaluates from left to right. Assuming that `(c1 or c2)` is truthy, it's equivalent to this:

```
if True in r':6':
```

Which obviously is not what you want. If you want it to work for several variables, this will do nicely:

```
if any(c in r':6' for c in (c1, c2, c3, c4)):
```

Comment: or-chains evaluates to the first truthy operand (or to the last one in the sequence, if none of them are truthy), not to 'True'.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Any way to make it less ugly? If you have more variables it could get quite tedious.

Comment: This will do, just fill the list with the variables to check in the text: `if any(c in txt for c in [c1, c2, ...]):`

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the precedent given to the operators.  The use of ()'s means that `c1 or c2`  is evaluated first.  It evaluates to True or False.  So your statement converts to

```
if bool in r':g'
```

Which is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Because `(c1 or c1)` evaluates as the value of the first variable, if it is not "false"(which means false, 0 or an empty string) or the value of the second variable.

Programming languages don't work like "natural languages".