# Python multiple if search in one string

Tags: python

I´m a network engineer with no experience in programming, recently in python, but making small improvements everyday.

I need some help in getting multiple matches in IF statements like:

```
if  "access-class 30" in output and "exec-timeout 5 5" in output:
    print ('###### ACL VTY OK!!! ######')
```

Is it possible to check multiple keywords in a single string ?
Thanks for all your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `all` function with a generator expression:

```
data = ["access-class 30", "exec-timeout 5 5"]
if all(s in output for s in data):
    print('###### ACL VTY OK!!! ######')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can use regular expressions(Regex).

```
import re
li = [] # List of all the keywords
for l in li
  for m in re.finditer(l,output)
     if m !=None:
       print 'match found'
```