# How does next() work in this python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I found some code I needed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37401376/1727657. But I don't understand what `next()` does *in this context*.  Could someone explain?

Here's a short test script I made to understand it.  The idea is to see whether the test string `txt` contains any of the strings in `myset` and, if so, which one.  It works but I don't know why.

```
myset = ['one', 'two', 'three']
txt = 'A two dog night'
match = next((x for x in myset if x in txt), False)
if match: #if match is true (meaning something was found)
   print match  #then print what was found
else:
   print "not found"
```

My next question will be to ask whether `next()` will give me the index of `match` (or do I need to do `find()` on `txt`)?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next

Comment: I'm guessing they use ``next`` here because they only want the first match. The line could have just been ``match = [x for x in myset if x in txt]`` to get all the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To explain how next is used in detail here.

```
match = next((x for x in myset if x in txt), False)
```

This will return the first/next value (**in this case the actual word that matched**) created by the generator expression passed in the first argument. If the generator expression is empty, then `False` will be returned instead.

Whoever wrote the code was probably only interested in the first match, so `next` was used.

We could just use:

```
matches = [x for x in myset if x in txt]
```

and just use `len` to determine the number of hits.

To show some plain usage of `next`:

```
generator = (x for x in myset)
print generator
print next(generator)
print next(generator)
print next(generator)
```

Outputs:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x100720b90>
one
two
three
```

The example above will trigger a `StopIteration` exception if we try to call `next` when the list/generator is empty because we don't use the second argument to override what should be returned when the generator is empty.

What `next` is really doing under the hood is called the type's `__next__()` method. This is important to keep mind when making classes.

If anything is unclear, do not hesitate to commend and I'll elaborate. Also remember that `print` is your friend when you don't understand what is going on.