# Why is second argument not detected in Python Coroutines?

Tags: python, coroutine

I have modified some code from [Coroutines](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/coroutines.html) as follows:

```
def grep(p1, p2):
    print("Searching for", p1 ,"and", p2)
    while True:
        line = (yield)
        if (p1 or p2) in line:
            print(line)

search = grep('love', 'woman')
next(search)
search.send("I love you")
search.send("Don't you love me?")
search.send("I love coroutines instead!")   
search.send("Beatiful woman")
```

Output:

> Searching for love and woman
>   I love you
>   Don't you love me?
>   I love coroutines instead!

Second argument `"woman"` is not recognized in the last search. Why is that?

Comment: If you type `a = "love" and b = ''woman"` in python interpreter and if we perform `a or b` it returns `love`

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition should be like this:

```
if p1 in line or p2 in line:
```

because `(p1 or p2)` would return `p1` as long as there's something in it.
so your current condition always evaluates to `if p1 in line:`

Answer (score 0):

Because your code condition is either of two arguments(p1 or p2) matches it return only p1 thats why it donot return the last send function result.
Now try this code .

Also I am attach the screenshot of output of the code.

```
 def grep(p1, p2):
        print("Searching for", p1 ,"and", p2)
        while True:
            line = (yield)
            if (p1) in line:
                print(line)
            if (p2) in line:
                print(line)

    search = grep('love', 'woman')
    next(search)
    search.send("I love you")
    search.send("Don't you love me?")
    search.send("I love coroutines instead!")   
    search.send("beautiful woman")
```

[image]