# function to get rid of delimeters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function where the user passes in a file and a String and the code should get rid of the specificed delimeters. I am having trouble finishing the part where I loop through my code and get rid of each of the `replacements`. I will post the code down below

```
def forReader(filename):
try:
    # Opens up the file
    file = open(filename , "r")
    # Reads the lines in the file
    read = file.readlines()
    # closes the files
    file.close()
        # loops through the lines in the file
    for sentence in read:
            # will split each element by a spaace
            line = sentence.split()
    replacements = (',', '-', '!', '?' '(' ')' '<' ' = ' ';')
    # will loop through the space delimited line and get rid of
    # of the replacements
    for sentences in line:




# Exception thrown if File does not exist
except FileExistsError:
    print('File is not created yet')


forReader("mo.txt")
```

`mo.txt`

```
for ( int i;
```

After running the file`mo.txt` I would like for the output to look like this
`for int i`

Comment: I assume this is homework. Are you allowed to use Regular Expressions?

Comment: haha no this isn't homework. Its actually a side project a friend and I are doing. Yes regular expressions are fine. I am not familiar with python which is why I am having a hard time with this.

Comment: In that case, you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Comment: an example would be really helpful @PM2Ring

Comment: `str.maketrans` ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good idea! But you'll still need to clean up any runs of adjacent spaces created by the deletions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this using regex. First, we create a pattern consisting of all the delimiter characters, being careful to escape them, since several of those characters have special meaning in a regex. Then we can use `re.sub` to replace each delimiter with an empty string. This process can leave us with two or more adjacent spaces, which we then need to replace with a single space.

The Python `re` module allows us to compile patterns that are used frequently. Theoretically, this can make them more efficient, but it's a good idea to test such patterns against real data to see if it does actually help. :)

```
import re

delimiters = ',-!?()<=;'

# Make a pattern consisting of all the delimiters
pat = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in delimiters))

s = 'for ( int i;'

# Remove the delimiters
z = pat.sub('', s)

#Clean up any runs of 2 or more spaces
z = re.sub(r'\s{2,}', ' ', z)
print(z)
```

**output**

```
for int i
```

Comment: You are a life saver. If I have any more questions on this matter can I DM you?

Comment: @jsilva Glad to help. If you have further questions on this particular code you can post a comment here. But if you have a new question that's not directly related to the above code, then just ask a fresh question. :)

Comment: Okay so now what I want to do is check if a particular word is in our new list after taking out the delimeters. How can I do that for example I tried to do a basic loop that goes through the new list and check for the word but no luck

Comment: @jsilva That's a new question. :) But if you just want to test for a single word you can use the `in` operator to do that sort of thing. Eg, `s = 'this is a test sentence'; print('test' in s)`. However, that will also find partial words embedded inside other words, eg `'sent' in s` is True. And you may not want that.

Comment: @jsilva The safe way is to split your cleaned-up string into a list of words, and then you can safely use `in` with it. Eg, `'test' in s.split()`

Comment: well my plan is run this script against a java file so that for example if the java file has a for loop in it my script would say something like for loop starts here. then it would have like `i < 10` and say the variable i is less than 10. Its a parser to help those without programming knowledge understand code. I am doing a small part while my partner is working on some other parts.

Comment: @jsilva It sounds like you want to be able to test your cleaned-up string against a list of keywords. There are lots of SO questions about that, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string

Comment: thanks alot. I got alot of out of this conversation. Enjoy your day!