# Check if a list of partial strings is within a single string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hopefully the same question hasn't already been answered (I looked but could not find).

I have a list of partial strings:

```
date_parts = ['/Year', '/Month', '/Day',....etc. ]
```

and I have a string.
E.g.

```
string1 = "Tag01/Source 01/Start/Year"
```

or

```
string1 = "Tag01/Source 01/Volume"
```

What is the most efficient way, apart from using a for loop, to check if any of the date_parts strings are contained within the string?

For info, string1 in reality is actually another list of many strings and I would like to remove any of these strings that contain a string within the date_parts list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: Thanks blhsing, I actually saw that one but the title didn't draw me in. Looks like it's got the 'any' answer, however I like the regex answer as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile a regex from the partial strings. Use `re.escape()` in case they contain control characters in the regex language.

```
import re
date_parts = ['/Year', '/Month', '/Day']
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(s) for s in date_parts))
```

Then use `re.search()` to see if it matches.

```
string1 = "Tag01/Source 01/Start/Year"
re.search(pattern, string1)
```

The regex engine is probably faster than a native Python loop.

---

For your particular use case, consider concatenating all the strings, like

```
all_string = '\n'.join(strings+[''])
```

Then you can do them all at once in a single call to the regex engine.

```
pattern = '|'.join(f'.*{re.escape(s)}.*\n' for s in date_parts)
strings = re.sub(pattern, '', all_string).split('\n')[:-1]
```

Of course, this assumes that none of your strings has a `'\n'`. You could pick some other character that's not in your strings to join and split on if necessary. `'\f'`, for example, should be pretty rare. Here's how you might do it with `'@'`.

```
all_string = '@'.join(strings+[''])
pattern = '|'.join(f'[^@]*{re.escape(s)}[^@]*@' for s in date_parts)
strings = re.sub(pattern, '', all_string).split('@')[:-1]
```

---

If that's still not fast enough, you could try a faster regex engine, like [rure](https://pypi.org/project/rure/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `any` function with a list comprehension. It should be a little faster than a `for` loop.

For one string, you can test like this:

```
any(p in string1 for p in date_parts)
```

If `strings` is a list of many strings you want to check, you could do this:

```
unmatched = [s for s in strings if not any(p in s for p in date_parts)]
```

or

```
unmatched = [s for s in strings if all(p not in s for p in date_parts)]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I would mark this as an answer along with glich's but only one answer.. the any method was marked as the answer in the post blhsing linked, so I gave the answer to regex in mine. cheers!

Comment: No worries! If you really care about speed, you could try the [Aho-Corasick Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) mentioned in the duplicate question thread. I’d be interested to see how it compares to regex. Both should be faster than `any`, but sometimes simplicity is better than speed.