# How to check if a string contains substring when both are stored in lists in python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, textblob

My main string is in dataframe and substrings are stored in lists. My desired output is to find the matched substring. Here is the code I am using.

```
sentence2 = "Previous study: 03/03/2018 (other hospital)  Findings:   Lung parenchyma: The study reveals evidence of apicoposterior segmentectomy of LUL showing soft tissue thickening adjacent surgical bed at LUL, possibly post operation." 
blob_sentence = TextBlob(sentence2)
noun = blob_sentence.noun_phrases
df1 = pd.DataFrame(noun)
comorbidity_keywords = ["segmentectomy","lobectomy"]
matches =[]
for comorbidity_keywords[0] in df1:
    if comorbidity_keywords[0] in df1 and comorbidity_keywords[0] not in matches:
       matches.append(comorbidity_keywords)
```

This gives me the result as the string that is not an actual match. The output should be "segmentectomy". But I get [0,'lobectomy']. Please Help!!. I have tried to take help from the answer posted here.  [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string) Please help to find out what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Begin with fixing `for comorbidity_keywords[0] in df1:` - you're essentially iterating over your `DataFrame` storing each row as the first element of your `comorbidity_keywords` list. Replace that line with something like `for keyword in comorbidity_keywords:` and then use `keyword` instead of `comorbidity_keywords[0]` in your `if...` check.

Comment: @zwer Edited like this  ` matches =[] `     
for keyword in comorbidity_keywords:
    if keyword in df1 and keyword not in matches:
        matches.append(keyword)   But this gives empty results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really use TextBlob, but I have two methods that might help you get to your goal.  Essentially, I'm splitting the sentence by a whitespace and iterating through that to see if there are any matches.  One method returns a list and the other a dictionary of index values and the word.

```
### If you just want a list of words
def find_keyword_matches(sentence, keyword_list):
    s1 = sentence.split(' ')
    return [i for i in  s1 if i in keyword_list]
```

Then:

```
find_keyword_matches(sentence2, comorbidity_keywords)
```

Output:

```
['segmentectomy']
```

For a dictionary:

```
def find_keyword_matches(sentence, keyword_list):
    s1 = sentence.split(' ')
    return {xyz.index(i):i for i in xyz if i in comorbidity_keywords}
```

Output:

```
{17: 'segmentectomy'}
```

Finally, an iterator that will also print where in the sentence a word is found, if at all:

```
def word_range(sentence, keyword):
    try:
        idx_start = sentence.index(keyword)
        idx_end = idx_start + len(keyword)
        print(f'Word \'{keyword}\' found within index range {idx_start} to {idx_end}')
        if idx_start > 0:
            return keyword
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Then do a nested list comprehension to get rid of None values:

```
found_words = [x for x in [word_range(sentence2, i) for i in comorbidity_keywords] if not x is None]
```

Comment: This is more than what I wanted to do. Thanks mate!!

Comment: What if my sentences are stored in a dataframe and I want to iterate over each sentence in a dataframe? Could you please help?

Comment: @pari Are your sentences in a single column or multiple columns?

Comment: I implemented a basic for loop to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There should be some more efficient way to do this. But this is what I have come up with using two for loops for two lists.

```
for ckeyword in comorbidity_keywords:
   for keyword in df1.values.tolist():
     if any(ckeyword in key for key in keyword):
        matches.append(ckeyword)
```