# Shortest way to check wether a list of strings occur in a string

Tags: python, string, syntactic-sugar

I would like to know the quickest or the shortest way to check if all the strings in a list occur in another specific string.
Ex:

```
l = ['I','you']
s = ['I do like you']
```

in this case, I would like to see if both `I` and `you` appear in `I do like you`. Is there a one-liner? Instead of a for loop and checking one by by manually, in a traditional way?

Comment: `all(w in s for w in l)`? Assuming `s` is actually the string `'I do like you'`, and not a list with the string. If `s` is a list of strings and you want to check against all of them then `all(w in t for w in l for t in s)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) which returns a `True` if all elements of the iterable are truthy or else `False`:

```
all(x in s[0] for x in l)
```

In **code**:

```
l = ['I','you']
s = ['I do like you']

print(all(x in s[0] for x in l))
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) operator, which returns `True` if every element of an Iterator is `True` or if it is empty.

```py
l = ['I', 'you']
s = 'I do like you'
print(all(x in s for x in l))
```

You might be intereseted by the [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) operator, which returns `True` if at least one element is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the words and not just strings.  For this use:

`all(_ in s[0].split() for _ in l)`