# Check Substring Match and Create New List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

This problem feels basic and I must be overlooking something obvious. There are many posts on Stack related to this but nothing I have found quite covers this use case.

I have two lists - One with URLs and one with substrings:

```
list1 = ['https://', 'http://', 'woof://', 'meow://']
list2 = ['https://google.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'meow://test.net', 'yahoo.com']
```

I want to create a third list where all the values from `list1` are removed from list2.

For example - `list3 = ['google.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'test.net', 'yahoo.com']`

I have tried:

```
for x in list1:
    for y in list2:
        if x in y:
            list3.append(y.replace(x, '')
        else:
            list3.append(y)
```

This creates a list with a lot of duplicates. I could probably add logic to clean `list3` up but I feel as though there must be a much more pythonic way to do this.

I feel like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string) is close to what I am looking for but not quite there.

Comment: You can use regex. `[re.sub("|".join(list1), "", x).strip(":/") for x in list2]` should work for your case- I'm sure there's a dupe...

Comment: Note: you are removing more than just the substrings in `list1`. None of them have `"//"` but you are removing that anyway. Do you want to parse the strings in `list2` as URLs and remove the `<protocol>://` prefix if it exists?

Comment: @pault Not sure how that code works its over my head but its exactly what I wanted thanks!!  If you post the answer I will accept

Comment: simplest way to not have duplicates is to use a set.

Comment: @AndrewAllen - I understand that but the issue is that doesn't help with dups like `google.com` and `https://google.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce
[reduce(lambda x, y: x.strip(y), list1, e) for e in list2]
['google.com', 'stackoverflow.com', 'test.net', 'yahoo.com']
```