# Is there a better way to do booleans?

Tags: python, for-loop, boolean

```
if "a_string" in random_word or "b_string" in random_word:
    ...
```

Is there a cleaner, less dense way to write this boolean?

Comment: The parameter to `for` is not a boolean. `for` has to be followed by a variable name.

Comment: whoops meant if

Comment: Duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 0):

In case of `if`, you could use `any` to check for the occurrence of either of the two strings

```
if any(i in random_word for i in ["a_string", "b_string"]):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
import re
if re.search(r'a_string|b_string', random_word):
    ...
```