# How to search text more quickly?

Tags: python, search

I want to know if the text contain any text of the list.

I wrote the code below.

But it needs for-loop, I think it is possible to be more quickly.

Pleas tell me faster code?

```py
subject_type_list = ['dog','cat','sheep','turtle']
searched_text = 'wertyuisdfghdog;;rtyuiobnmcatuio'

def confirm_existence():
    for search_word in subject_type_list:
        if search_word in searched_text:
            return True
    return False

confirm_existence()
```

Comment: Dear y_ito_htec, please let us know what all have you tried. There are numerous posts on internet (and on Stackoverflow as well) which tells you how to find an item in the list in various ways. In case they are not working according to you need, please specify what problem you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: @Taegyung did you mean a [DFA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) ? KMP is implemented as a DFA but is specified for a single string searched.

Comment: @MichaelDoubez No, I did mean KMP, but after looking up the implementation, it seems that the built-in string search is a variation of Boyer-Moore, so using KMP won't help much.

Comment: Have you tried using regex?

Comment: @Henry Yik No I haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can discard the `for` loop by using regular expressions. There is an excellent manual [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Whether this will be faster depends mostly on the number of search patterns and the length of the string.  If you have a large number of search patterns and/or long search strings, a solution with regular expressions will be faster.   Something like this should do the trick.

```
import re

subject_type_list = ["dog", "cat", "sheep", "turtle"]
searched_text = "wertyuisdfghdog;;rtyuiobnmcatuio"

pattern = re.compile(r"|".join(subject_type_list))
matches = pattern.find(searched_text)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll adopt regex to support added subject_type_list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, and I'd say it's the normal way to solve the problem. If you're looking for something more concise, you can rewrite your function using `any`:

```
subject_type_list = ['dog','cat','sheep','turtle']
searched_text = 'wertyuisdfghdog;;rtyuiobnmcatuio'

def confirm_existence():
    return any(x in searched_text for x in subject_type_list)

print( confirm_existence() ) # True
```

Or just use `any` outright:

```
subject_type_list = ['dog','cat','sheep','turtle']
searched_text = 'wertyuisdfghdog;;rtyuiobnmcatuio'

print( any(x in searched_text for x in subject_type_list) ) # true
```

Comment: This is basically same as author's defined function, and i think he wanted a better way to search.

Comment: @HenryYik Yes. I want to a better way to search more quickly.

Comment: @IsmaelPadilla The shorter code makes me easy to see. But the run time is almost same.