# Can we check if two or more sub strings are in string in python

Tags: python, string, if-statement, substring

I am trying to make a program that can check if two or more sub strings are in 1 string using python, can you tell me how can i do this

```
str = "I like apple do you like apples?"

if 'apples' or 'like' in str:
    print('yes, I like apples')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes it worked thankyou frnd, sorry for responding late,

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is:

```
if 'apples' in str or 'like' in str:
    print('yes, I like apples')
```

The reason for this is that the `or` operator will divide an `if` statement into sections so with your original version:

```
if 'apples' or 'like' in str
```

you are essentially asking:

```
if 'apples'
or
if 'like' in str
```

and because if you have any `if` statement with simply a string that string will equate to `true` and so you are asking `if true` `or` `if 'like' in str` and because `true` is always `true` it will be true even if neither substring is in the string you are searching.