# How do I check a string for multiple words?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to check a line of output from my code, to see if it contains "Active: Exited" or "Active: Inactive".

I've tried to use:
`if "Active: Exited" or "Active; Inactive" in output:`
but this just triggers no matter what is in the output.

If I just say:
`if "Active: Exited" in output:` it works as it's supposed to.

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `in` test does not distribute.
What you're trying to say is

```
if ("Active: Exited" or "Active; Inactive") in output:
```

but Python interprets this as

```
if ("Active: Exited") or ("Active; Inactive" in output):
```

in which case the string `"Active: Excited"` is so-called 'truthy', so your `or` always evaluates to `True`.

What you want is this:

```
if "Active: Exited" in output or "Active; Inactive" in output:
# AKA
# if ("Active: Exited" in output) or ("Active; Inactive" in output):
```

Comment: @Toftegaard if this answer helped you, please don't forget to upvote and accept :)

Comment: Ohh, didn't see the "mark as answer" button :D
I'll do that right away.