# Python Check if given multiple substrings are in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I need to check if a couple of substrings are in a list. I found the following codes. But it takes only one string.

```
test_list = ['GeeksforGeeks', 'Geeky', 'Computers', 'Algorithms'] 
subs = 'Geek'
res = [i for i in test_list if subs in i] 
print ("All strings with given substring are : " + str(res))
```

What should I do if I want to find two substrings such as 'Geek' and 'Algo'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: In question by link read `str = "a123"` as `str = ['a', '1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I thought I had to separate keywords.

Answer (score 0):

it will get all matches as Geek is two times matches will contain two Geek

```
import re 
test_list = ['GeeksforGeeks', 'Geeky', 'Computers', 'Algorithms'] 
test_list = ' '.join(test_list)
subs = 'Geek,Algo'
matches = re.findall(r'Geek|Algo', test_list, re.IGNORECASE)
print(set(matches)
print(set((matches))
```

if you want to get unique 
just add this line