# Arrays.asList returns false

Tags: java, string, arraylist, contains

I just wanna check if my String[] array contains "n" or "s".

```
String[] coordinatesExample = {"57.8136°s", "28.3496°e"};

private void isContains(String[] coordinates) {

    boolean contains = Arrays.asList(coordinates).contains("s");
        if (contains) {
            System.out.println("It works!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("RAKAMAKAFO");
        }
```

So I expected: "It works!", but
in fact: "RAKAMAKAFO"

What I did wrong?

Comment: `"57.8136°s"`contains `"s"`, `{"57.8136°s", "28.3496°e"}` doesn't

Comment: .contains() on ArrayList will return true if entire element exist. You are checking only "s".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution only works if you have a String Array like this:

```
String[] coordinatesExample = {"57.8136°s", "28.3496°e", "s"};
```

Try this if you want to check if any String from your Array contains "n" or "s".

```
private static void isContains(String[] coordinates) {
    boolean contains = Arrays.stream(coordinates)
            .anyMatch(coordinate -> coordinate.contains("s") || coordinate.contains("n"));
    if (contains) {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("RAKAMAKAFO");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `Arrays.asList(coordinates)` you get the list containing two items: `57.8136°s` and `28.3496°e`. So using `.contains("s")` you test if any of your items is "s" which is obviously not the case.

Comment: Apologize.Obviously I didn't know how it's work.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Contains only checks to see if the list contains one of the elements which `s` is not one.

From the JavaDoc for the `List` interface

> boolean contains​(Object o)
>
> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that Objects.equals(o, e).

If you did the following, it would return print `It works!` because the `first string` in the list contained an `s`

```
private static void isContains(String[] coordinates) {

    boolean contains = Arrays.asList(coordinates).get(0).contains("s");
        if (contains) {
            System.out.println("It works!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("RAKAMAKAFO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I know another one method and solution  <3