# Python function with if-else statement outputting incorrectly

Tags: python, if-statement

why is my function outputting incorrectly? I am thinking something is working wrong with the if-else statements but idk.

```
def standardize_gender(gen):
    gen = gen.strip()
    gen = gen.lower()

    if 'female' or 'f' or 'woman' or 'famale' or 'women' in gen:
        put = 'female'
    elif 'male' or 'man' or 'm' or 'men' in gen:
        put = 'male'
    elif 'nonbinary' or 'transgender' in gen:
        put = 'nonbinary_or_trans'
    else:
        put = np.nan
    return put

standardize_gender('male') #Outputs 'female'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 2):

This is because your expression actually looks something like this

```
('female') or ('f') or ('woman') or ('famale') or ('women' in gen)
```

Since 'female' is not an empty string, the first if block is entered.

What you probably want is something like this:

```
if any(x in gen for x in ['female', 'f', 'woman', 'famale', 'women']):
  put = 'female'
```

The `any` function takes an iterable and returns `True` if any one of them is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4518341). The comprehension (everything inside the parentheses) provides that by going through every element in the list `['female', 'f', 'woman', 'famale', 'women']` and checking if that element (`x`) is present in `gen`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `or` statement is wrong - you have to do something like `if 'female' in gen or if 'woman' in gen...`, (each individually). Yours is basically saying `if 'female'` , which would be considered `True`.

Comment: Don't do them individually, use `any` like the other answers recommend

Answer (score 0):

When you use `or` in your if statement, it checks if the left of the `or` is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/4518341). When you write `if 'female':` in python, a non-empty string is truthy so the program continues into the if block. This is why you are getting "female" all the time. To avoid this, you can use:

```py
female_conditions = ['female', 'f', 'woman', 'famale', 'women']
if any(cond in gen for cond in female_conditions):
    # do something here
```