# Python syntax for “if a and b or a and c” where a, b and c are words in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, operators

I have a python script, and I should check if two words are present in a sentence separated by dash

```
test_dash_sentence="wordtest-wordtest-word3-word4"

if ("word1" and "word2") or ("word1" and "word3") in test_dash_sentence:
    print("FOUND")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

The issue I have is that is return me "FOUND" even if `word1` is not present, so it should return me "NOT FOUND"

I have tried different models (with simple quotation, without parentheses) and it seems to work if I only look for one word in the sentence, but when I look for two words, it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Comment: @PM77-1 Not entirely, because in your link, they look for a or b or c in a string, and I look for a and b `or` a and c

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you assume that the `and` and `or` syntax is aggrgated to the `in` later, but this is not true...
and you if statment translated to `of True in test_dash_sentence:` because the statement is casting strings to boolean.. as follows:

```
if ("word1" and "word2") or ("word1" and "word3"):
   print(True):
else:
   print(False)
>>> True
```

**solution:**

just change:

```
if ("word1" and "word2") or ("word1" and "word3") in test_dash_sentence:
```

to:

```
if ("word1" in test_dash_sentence and "word2" in test_dash_sentence) or ("word1" in test_dash_sentence and "word3" in test_dash_sentence) :
```

EDIT: as commented by @JohnnyMopp below you can also make the statement shorter so just:

```
if ("word1" in test_dash_sentence) and ("word2" in test_dash_sentence or  "word3" in test_dash_sentence) :
```

**MORE EXPLAINATION BY REQUEST**

python does not support the syntax of `(element1 and element2 ) in mylist`, the `in` keyword can be only applied to one element at a time so instead you must do `element1 in list and element2 in mylist`, what happening is python treat `(element1 and element2 )` as a separate statement, evaluates it to boolean and then check if the resulting boolean is exist in the `mylist`.

Comment: Since you have `"word1" in test_dash_sentence` twice, you can combine and make shorter.

Comment: Note that `if ("word1" and "word2") or ("word1" and "word3") in test_dash_sentence`  is evaluated as `if (True and True) or ...` which evaluates as True

Comment: Thanks @adirabargil for the details I gave you 1 upvote, your answer solve the main issue, however I am worried applying it to large quantity of data make it really hard to read and to maintain

Comment: if you will show demonstration of how the data is expanding we can find a way the is more readable and generic, but for your current example i did my best... i think it is an appropriate answer... anyway @azro answer might answer your needs if the conditions are meeting the situation...

Comment: Indeed you have answered perfectly to the main problem, and quickly, I thank you for it. Also people rarely think about it, but thank you to upvote the question if it seems relevant to you.

Comment: with pleasure... if you find this answer helpful you are welcome to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You must repeat `in test_dash_sentence` for each word, with the simplification of `word1` being in both clauses, you get

```
if "word1" in test_dash_sentence and ("word2" in test_dash_sentence or "word3" in test_dash_sentence):
```

You can also use `all/any`

```
required = ['word1']         # all of them must be found
any_of = ['word2', 'word3']  # at least one of them must be found

if all(w in test_dash_sentence for w in required) and \
   any(w in test_dash_sentence for w in any_of):
    print("FOUND")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

---

For multiple possible required word having each their optionnal words (one must match), you can use a `dict` to store, and a `2-level` `any` then

```
words = {
    'w1': ['opt1', 'opt2'],
    'w2': ['opt4', 'opt5', 'opt44', 'opt55'],
    'w3': ['opt6', 'opt7'],
}

if any(
        required in test_dash_sentence and any(w in test_dash_sentence for w in any_of)
        for required, any_of in words.items()
):
    print("FOUND")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain what does `w`represent in your second part ? I find it quite confusing

Comment: @Ced that is a local function, that represent the word from the array, either `required` or `any_of`, it is used for the test `w in test_dash_sentence`

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification, how would you arrange the second part, to do the same but for a lot of data, let's say for instance I have 3 required words, and each of them uniquely have their 4 optional words corresponding (all unique to their respective required words)

Comment: Thanks, but in the edit you use `required` and `any_of` while only having a `dict` called `words` so I don't see how could it works, did I miss something?

Comment: @Ced they come from `for required, any_of in words.items()`

Comment: it does works but I can't fully explain why, could you please add comments and find a way to make it more beginner friendly ? for instance, I don't get how `required` takes the first `dict` level and `any_of` the second level of the `dict`

Comment: @Ced that is what `.items` works, it returns a pair of key/value (there is no **level**, just key and value)

Comment: Ok but how does it know `required` refer to the key, and `any_of` to a value ?

Comment: @Ced `items()` generates pairs of key/value, so `for a,b in mydict.items()` generates the pairs, `a` as key, `b` as value

Answer (score 0):

your boolean condition is not correct. Also, `"word1"` is twice in your condition, so you can combine them:

```
test_dash_sentence="wordtest-wordtest-word2-word3"

if "word1" in test_dash_sentence and ("word2" in test_dash_sentence or "word3" in test_dash_sentence):
    print("FOUND")
else:
    print("NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and welcome to StackOverflow ! don't hesitate to also upvote the question if it seems relevant to you! :)