# Python: How to use list of keywords to search for a string in a text

Tags: python, if-statement, directory, python-3.8, listdir

So I'm writing a program that loops through multiple .txt files and searches for any number of pre-specified keywords. I'm having some trouble finding a way to pass through the keywords list to be searched for.

The code below currently returns the following error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

I'm aware that the error is caused by the keyword list but I have no idea how to input a large array of keywords without it running this error.

Current code:

```
from os import listdir

keywords=['Example', 'Use', 'Of', 'Keywords']
 
with open("/home/user/folder/project/result.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in listdir("/home/user/folder/project/data"):
        with open('/home/user/folder/project/data/' + filename) as currentFile:
            text = currentFile.read()
            #Error Below
            if (keywords in text):
                f.write('Keyword found in ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
            else:
                f.write('No keyword in ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
```

The error is indicated in line 10 in the above code under the commented section. I'm unsure as to why I can't call a list to be able to search for the keywords. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand? You cannot use the `in` operator to see if a `list` is in a `str`. That is not a defined operation. Like, you want to check if any of the strings in your list is in the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
if (keywords in text):
   ...
```

with

```
if any(keyword in text for keyword in keywords):
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks, was searching forever and this was the best fix!

Answer (score 0):

try looping through the list to see if each element is in the text

```py
for i in range(0, len(keywords)):
    if keywords[i] in text:
        f.write('Keyword found in ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
        break
    else:
        f.write('No keyword in ' + filename[:-4] + '\n')
        break
```

you cannot use `in` too see if a list is in a string

Comment: I'm all about more breaks during the day, but maybe just one `break` in this code suffices?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) as they are purpose-built for searching text for substrings.

You only need the `re.search` block.  I added examples of `findall` and `finditer` to demystify them.

```
# lets pretend these 4 sentences in `text` are 4 different files
text = '''Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum'''.split(sep='. ')

# add more keywords
keywords=[r'publishing', r'industry']
regex = '|'.join(keywords)
import re
for t in text:
    lst = re.findall(regex, t, re.I) # re.I make case-insensitive
    for el in lst:
        print(el)

    iterator = re.finditer(regex, t, re.I)
    for el in iterator:
        print(el.span())

    if re.search(regex, t, re.I):
        print('Keyword found in `' + t + '`\n')
    else:
        print('No keyword in `' + t + '`\n')
```

Output:

```
industry
(65, 73)
Keyword found in `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry`

industry
(25, 33)
Keyword found in `Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book`

No keyword in `It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged`

publishing
(132, 142)
Keyword found in `It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum`
```

Comment: I found that regex made some conflicts in the code using it in the past but will give it another shot. Thanks for a solution!

Comment: @StephenFlynn Hopefully using regex again is now possible for you?  Give the `re.search` a gander and let me know results.