# how to find many character in python without using OR?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
a = '/dvi/abcbbb'

if ('/dev/' in a) or ('/dv/' in a) or ('/dvi/' in a):
     print(a)
/dvi/abcbbb
```

Can we do it without the OR statements in Python ?

Comment: `if any(x in a for x in ('/dev', '/dv/', '/dvi/')):`

Comment: Check out this thread --  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string/)

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the check:

```
if os.path.dirname(a) in ["/dev", "/dv", "/dvi"]:
    print(a)
```