# Finding elements of a list and printing it out

Tags: python

i am still learning python and i am struggling to find a way to get this to work the way i want.

```
#First Method

staticPaths = [
    "[N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-480]", 
    "[N4-OLDCLOUD-IPSTORAGE/epg-N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[vlan-481]]",
    "['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-484]",
    "['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-485]",
    "['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C01-N2][vlan-480]"
]
```

```
for path in staticPaths:

   filter_object = filter(lambda a: 'vlan-480' in a, staticPaths)

print(list(filter_object))
```

So what i am trying to do here is filter out anything that matches ‘vlan-480’ and return the entire line, so for example, if i run that code, i receive the correct output. which would be -
**[N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C01-N2][vlan-480]
['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-480]**

However where is states ‘vlan-480’ in the lambda function i actually want to pass it a LIST but because i am using the “in” statement, it only allows me to pass a single string.

Again i want to check multiples, so for example, give me the output for ‘vlan-480’ AND ‘vlan-484’ and it should return the lines for me from the staticPaths

I cannot think of way of getting this done, might just be me been stupid but for some reason i cannot solve it.

Also tried an if statement but i have the same problem, with the single string option.

```
#Second Method

path_matches = []

for path_match in staticPaths:
  if 'vlan-480' in path_match:
     path_matches.append(path_match)

print(path_matches)
```

Can anyone think of a way of doing this, its probably really easy but for some reason i cannot think of it. I did try and use List Comprehension but struggled to get the output i needed.

much appericated

Comment: `for path in staticPaths:` is not necessary, `filter` already does that for you

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string/3389611) help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
substrings = ['vlan-480', 'vlan-484']

filter_object = filter(lambda a: any(x in a for x in substrings), staticPaths)

print(list(filter_object))
```

The list `substrings` contains substrings to search for

The output I get for your dataset is:

```
['[N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-480]', "['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-484]", "['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C01-N2][vlan-480]"]
```

Comment: ohhh let me try that, that looks good thank you

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: this is perfect and is working, thats brilliant thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension

```
substrings = ['vlan-480', 'vlan-484']

path_matches = [x for x in staticPaths if substrings[0] in x or substrings[1] in x]
```

that results in :

```
path_matches

['[N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-480]',
"['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C02-N2][vlan-484]",
"['N4-NFS-NETAPP-8040-C01]/[N4-NHT-LEAF-VPC-FAS-C01-N2][vlan-480]"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is with indentation i guess check this

```
path_matches = []

for path_match in staticPaths:
    if 'vlan-480' in path_match:
        path_matches.append(path_match)
```

Comment: yeah its not indentation. Its i need to pass a list into the if statement.

Comment: I thought you want only for 480 but yeah in that case its list instead of string

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
filter_object = filter(lambda a: 'vlan-480' in a or 'vlan-484' in a, staticPaths)

print(list(filter_object))
```

To do multi selection you can use operator OR/AND, so it will be such this 'vlan-480' in a or 'vlan-484' in a

Comment: i will try that, anyway i can use another list in that function.