# How can I check if multiple words appear in a sentence?

Tags: python, list, discord, any

I seem unable to find the solution as to why this doesn't work
here's the line of code:

```
if ("yeah" or "yes") in message.content:
  await message.channel.send("yep")
else:
  await message.channel.send("nope")
```

I tried using any and even a word list but it didn't work either

what I mean to say is that if any of the words "yeah" or "yes" (or even more) appear in a sentence then the bot must send "yep" if not then it should say "nope"

Comment: Could you fix the indentation in your code?

Comment: Also I believe [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389611/9822480) is what you are after.

Comment: @bluecouch I tried understanding what was being explained in that solution but I still don't get it, i'm a huge beginner in coding

Comment: No worries, I'll add an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check against multiple values using a combination of `in` and `any`. It essentially creates a list of boolean values, then checks if any of them are true (i.e. one of the words exists in the message).

```
if any(x in message.content for x in ["yeah", "yes"]):
    # send "yep"
else:
    # send "nope"
```

This solution is based off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389611)

Comment: is x supposed to be something? or should it be left as is? thanks for typing it out!

Comment: `x` is a variable that is set to each value in the list as it iterates of the list. For example, `x` will become `"yeah"` and then `"yes"` in this example, at which point it is checked if it is in `message.content`. So you can leave `x` as is.