# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list | discord.py

Tags: discord.py, nextcord

```
if ["a", "e"] in msg.content:
```

Im trying to search in on_message if any words of the list is on the message content but i get this error

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Comment: `in` expects a string on the left side , not a list of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, a string is expected on the left side. From your example it is not clear to me if you want to check if all strings are in msg.content or if any of them are in msg.content. So here are both cases:

```
if all(_ in msg.content for _ in ["a", "e"]):
```

or

```
if any(_ in msg.content for _ in ["a", "e"]):
```