# Match string "words" with an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, replace

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389611/10315735) method to match a string with an array. However, I want to match entire words, instead of each character in a string.

```
string = "Take a pill when you are ill"
array = ['bill', 'chill', 'pill']
if any(x in string for x in array):
    string = string.replace('ill', 'sick')    
print(string)
```

I want this block of code to return:

> Take a pill when you are sick

But it returns:

> Take a psick when you are sick

How do I do this?

Comment: A string is an array of characters, so you can use `string.split(" ")` to give you an array, and use a for loop to check if the contents of `array` are in `string`

Comment: `string.replace(' ill', ' sick')` Change to this it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to only replace when a word appears on its own. `\b` matches word boundaries: it doesn't consume any characters but will only match at the boundary between word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`) and non-word characters.

```python3
import re

string = "Take a pill when you are ill"
array = ['bill', 'chill', 'pill']
if any(x in string for x in array):
    string = re.sub(r'\bill\b', 'sick', string)

print(string)
```

Comment: This is not working. It outputs the input exactly as it is.

Comment: My mistake: I forgot to use a raw string. I've now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to also match empty spaces:

```py
if any(x in string for x in array):
    string = string.replace(' ill ', ' sick ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the line

```
`if any(x in string for x in array):
string = string.replace('ill', 'sick')`
```

To

```
`if any(x in string for x in array):
string = string.replace(' ill', 'sick')`
```

Now it will only replace sick with ill

Comment: You could also split the string using `.split()` function then check the array and then replace the word in the array and join to make the sentence

Comment: Also You can Split the string then check with array and then join the array using `" ".join(array_name)` .

Comment: Yes, this seems like the solution that I need. Can you please elaborate the string splitting method?

Answer (score 0):

this code will check any 'ill' in the string and change it with 'sick'. What you can do is

`string = string.replace('ill', 'sick')`

replace this with
`string = string.replace(' ill', ' sick')`
this.