# Filter out elements from list if matching one of multiple patterns

Tags: python, list, filter

I have found solutions in different languages, but not Python. Having limited experience in coding except Python and R, I can't translate them properly.

I have a list of files like this:

```
file_list1 = ['/home/qrs/sample1.csv',
 '/home/abc/sample1.csv',
 '/home/mno/sample13.csv',
 '/home/xyz/sample2.csv']
```

I also have a list of folders like:

```
change_folder = ['mno', 'xyz']
```

Now i want to filter the file list where folders do not match as those in the folder list. The intended result would be:

```
file_list2 = ['/home/qrs/sample1.csv',
 '/home/abc/sample1.csv']
```

I have tried:

```
file_list2 = [x for x in file_list1 if change_folder not in x]
```

This only works if I have just one pattern, not for multiple patterns. Please help.

Edit: Got some of the answer in another question. However, the answer gotten here also includes elements that cater specifically to filtering path strings, which will be valuable for future visitors.
Already stated why this question is not a duplicate even if it seems similar to some other generic matching question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string) You just want to do this for each `x` in `file_list1`, and check  your condition for each `y` in `change_folder`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi this helps a lot in understanding the function. Weird how it didnt show up when searching for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to use [`Path.parts` API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) to check if a folder is part of a path. Also you can use `any` with generator expression to test the condition against multiple patterns.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> 
>>> 
>>> file_list1 = [
...     "/home/qrs/sample1.csv",
...     "/home/abc/sample1.csv",
...     "/home/mno/sample13.csv",
...     "/home/xyz/sample2.csv",
... ]
>>> 
>>> change_folder = ["mno", "xyz"]
>>> 
>>> r = [
...     path
...     for path in file_list1
...     if not any(folder in Path(path).parts for folder in change_folder)
... ]
>>> print(r)
['/home/qrs/sample1.csv', '/home/abc/sample1.csv']
```

Comment: works perfectly. Also adopted your suggestion to use Path.parts. Much more elegant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without libs or anything by just using basic functions i came up with this:

```
file_list1 = ['/home/qrs/sample1.csv', '/home/abc/sample1.csv', '/home/mno/sample13.csv', '/home/xyz/sample2.csv']
change_folder = ['mno', 'xyz']
output_list = file_list1.copy()

for i in range(len(file_list1)):  # loop through paths
    for folder in change_folder: # loop through folders
        if folder in file_list1[i]: # checks if the folder string is inside the path string
            output_list.pop(output_list.index(file_list1[i])) # pops the path out of the output list
print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
['/home/qrs/sample1.csv', '/home/abc/sample1.csv']
```

Comment: `output_list` is the same list as `file_list1`, and that is a code-smell since you are removing from the list you're iterating over. Maybe you meant to `.copy()` the list so that the two objects are identical but independent?

Comment: Jep, you're right. My mistake, Code is edited.