# Python case insensitive efficiently check if list of strings is contained in another string

Tags: python, string, list, substring, case-insensitive

I want to check if a list of string is contained in another string **but ignoring the case**

For example:

```
Input: 'Hello World', ['he', 'o w']
Output: [True, True]
Input: 'Hello World', ['he', 'wol']
Output: [True, False]
```

I can write something like:

```
output =[]
for keyword in keywordlist:
  if keyword.lower() in string.lower():
    output.append(True)
  else:
    output.append(False)
```

But the issues with this are:

1. the time complexity
2. using lower()

I have found this question on stack overflow which is similar [Check if multiple strings exist in another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389574/check-if-multiple-strings-exist-in-another-string)

But it doesn’t work for ignore case.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why do you say either of those things are an issue? (`casefold` would be more correct than `lower`, but that's both very easy to fix and almost certainly not what you had in mind.)

Comment: How long are the strings, how many are there, and please fix your invalid quote characters.

Comment: You don't need to continually call *lower()* on *string* just re-assign it before entering the loop

Answer (score 0):

This is probably quite efficient:

```
# make sure the input string is lowercase - do this only once
string = 'Hello World'.lower()
keywordlist = ['he', 'o w'] # all keywords assumed to be lowercase
output = [kw in string for kw in keywordlist]
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[True, True]
```