# best way count the number of matches between the list and the string in python

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-2.7

What is the best way to count the number of matches between the list and the string in python??

for example if I have this list:

```
list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

and this string:

```
line = "some one long. two phrase three and one again"
```

I want to get 4 because I have

```
one 2 times
two 1 time
three 1 time
```

I try below code based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271478/check-list-of-words-in-another-string) answers and it's worked but I got error if I add many many words (4000 words) to list:

```
import re
word_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
line = "some one long. two phrase three and one again"
words_re = re.compile("|".join(word_list))
print(len(words_re.findall(line)))
```

This is my error:

```
words_re = re.compile("|".join(word_list))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
```

Comment: I tried your list times a million with `re.compile("|".join(word_list * 1000000))` using Python 2.7.6 and I get no such error. The problem might be your word_list that needs `re.escape` for each word.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I used .split() function to create my word list. Please give more detail about ```re.escape``` if it's possible.

Comment: The error apparently caused by the size of the list might actually be caused by a word containing an invalid regular expression in the 4000 words list. So, each word should be escaped like this: `words_re = re.compile("|".join([re.escape(word) for word in word_list]))`

Comment: @cr3 our comment code worked. Please post it as answer and please compare regex based solution (your answer) and Malik Brahimi answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want case insensitive and to match whole words ignoring punctuation, split the string and strip the punctuation using a dict to store the words you want to count:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
from string import punctuation
cn = dict.fromkeys(lst, 0)
line = "some one long. two phrase three and one again"

for word in line.lower().split():
    word = word.strip(punctuation)
    if word in cn:
        cn[word] += 1


print(cn)

{'three': 1, 'two': 1, 'one': 2}
```

If you just want the sum use a *set* with the same logic:

```
from string import punctuation

st = {'one', 'two', 'three'}
line = "some one long. two phrase three and one again"

print(sum(word.strip(punctuation) in st for word in line.lower().split()))
```

This does a single pass over the the words after they are split, the set lookup is `0(1)` so it is substantially more efficient than `list.count`.