# Print the line of a word occurrence in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program that reads the content of a file, searches the file line by line and when certain strings occur, it returns me that line to my screen.

I have succeeded when it is only ONE string that I am looking for. What I am trying now is, when I tell Python to look for a number of strings and when one of them occurs in the file, it prints me that line

```
import urllib2
file = urllib2.urlopen("http://helloworldbook2.com/data/message.txt")
message = file.read()
#print message

# Saves the content of the URL in a file
temp_output = open("tempfile.txt", "w")
temp_output.write(message)
temp_output.close()

# Displays the line where a certain word occurs
wordline = [line for line in message.split('\n') if ("enjoying" or "internet") in line]
line = wordline[0]
print line
```

So my problem is the ("enjoying" or "internet") part.

Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3271485/3697202) might have the solution you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah that actually solved my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is no good:

```
if ("enjoying" or "internet")
```

Instead, you can use `any` or `all`:

```
words = ["enjoying", "internet"]
if all(x in line for x in words)
```