# Regular expression to match a line containing only the list of words

Tags: regex

Looking for a regular expression to match only the given list of words in a strings

The regular expression  pattern to match strings containing only **boy** or **apple** in the below list of strings

```
[apple, boy, apple, boy] 
[boy, boy, boy, boy] 
[apple, boy, boy, boy]
```

to match

```
[apple, boy, apple, boy]
[apple, boy, boy, boy]
```

Comment: See [Check list of words in another string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271478/check-list-of-words-in-another-string).

Comment: For future reference, and especially if you haven't actually done anything, just state your problem and let people that know better decide what tool works best. Regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: I understand this could be achieved in python in multiple ways, but I am looking for a pure regular expression approach.

Comment: You should clarify what language you are working with, as different languages have varying constructs and options for regular expressions. It sounds like you need one that allows you to match a previously matched pattern during its search. The structure of your data is not clear, either - your question could be interpreted to mean none of the strings you provided will match.

Comment: @karthikbharadwaj I hope you meant that the string should contain both apple **and** boy. And not apple **or** boy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it works:

```
(?=.*apple)(?=.*boy).*
```