# Fail to find multi-strings

Tags: python

```
about_pet = input("A sentence about your pet")
multi = "dog", "cat"
if all(multi) in about_pet:
    print ("wow, you have one more pets!", " Thanking you reading my 
story:) ")
elif "dog" in about_pet:
    print ("Ah, a dog.", " Thanking you reading my story:) ")
elif "cat" in about_pet:
    print ("Oh, a cat.", " Thanking you reading my story:) ")
```

i don't know how to search two strings in an input. The above captured is what I had done.

Comment: `if all(pet in about_pet for pet in multi)`

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271478/check-list-of-words-in-another-string. All is used incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

All works on an iterable, it returns true if all items within the iterable are true.

```
multi = ["dog", "cat"]
if all(m in about_pet for m in multi):
    print ("wow, you have one more pets!", " Thanking you reading my story:) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could put an if statement within an if statement so it checks if the sentence contains the word `cat` first then if it does it goes on check if it also contains the word `dog` to see if both words are in the string.

```
    about_pet = raw_input("A sentence about your pet")
    if "cat" in about_pet:
      if "dog"in about_pet:
        print "wow, you have one more pets! Thanking you reading my story:) "
    elif "dog" in about_pet:
        print "Ah, a dog. Thanking you reading my story:) "
    elif "cat" in about_pet:
        print "Oh, a cat. Thanking you reading my story:) "
```

I know this might not be the cleverest solution but it is quite easy to understand. 
To simplify it you can check them one after another using an `and`

```
    if "cat" in about_pet and "dog" in about_pet:
```

or:

```
    if "cat" and "dog" in about_pet:
```

If you are using Python 2.7.10 ,you also need to use `raw_input` instead of `input` as in Python 2.7.10 `input` only accepts integers and float. And if you're using python 2.7.10(as i am) i don't do my print in brackets as it prints out the brackets sometimes. Also i have a suggestion to add code for when the user says they don't have a pet using an `else` at the end. Plus you don't have to put sentences in separate speech marks. I hope this helped!

Comment: The two ifs can be replaced with an and.  if "cat" in about_pet and "dog"in about_pet

Comment: @Simon Black   Okay, thanks so would it be`if "cat" in about_pet and "dog" in about_pet"` or can it be `if "cat" and "dog" in about_pet` ?