# keyword inspection based on words present in multiple lists

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, dictionary, pattern-matching

I have a dictionary similar to this:

```
countries = ["usa", "france", "japan", "china", "germany"]
fruits = ["mango", "apple", "passion-fruit", "durion", "bananna"]

cf_dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(["countries", "fruits"], [countries, fruits])}
```

and I also have a list of strings similar to this:

```
docs = ["mango is a fruit that is very different from Apple","I like to travel, last year I was in Germany but I like France.it was lovely"]
```

I would like to inspect the `docs` and see if each string contains `any` of the keywords in any of the lists(the values of cf_dict are lists) in cf_dict, and if they are present then return the corresponding `key`(based on values) for that string(strings in docs) as output.

so for instance, if I inspect the list `docs` the output will be [`fruits`, `countries`]

something similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3271485/4038206) but this checks only one list, however, I would like to check multiple lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following returns a dict of sets in case a string matches values in more than one list (e.g. `'apple grows in USA'` should be mapped to `{'fruits', 'countries'}`).

```
print({s: {k for k, l in cf_dict.items() for w in l if w in s.lower()} for s in docs})
```

This outputs:

```
{'mango is a fruit that is very different from Apple': {'fruits'}, 'I like to travel, last year I was in Germany but I like France.it was lovely': {'countries'}}
```